# Why doesn't wp_enqueue_script() work when including a JavaScript file with TEMPLATEPATH?

Tags: hooks, javascript, themes

I am trying to use tips from **[here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site)** to add my JS file.

I put the following in the functions.php of atahualpa theme I've got installed

```
function lektor_init() {
  if (true) {
    wp_enqueue_script('lektor',TEMPLATEPATH.'/js/synteza.js');
  }
}
add_action('init','lektor_init');
```

`TEMPLATEPATH` has been already used before in there, so I just adapted it.
But it doesn't show up.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Mine was first, but ok :P

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`TEMPLATEPATH` is a directory path, not a url. You'll need to use `get_template_directory_uri()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
function parent_theme_name_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'lektor', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/synteza.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'parent_theme_name_scripts' );
```

Add to your parents themes functions file.

However, if you're adding scripts to a parent theme, [create a child theme](http://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) and add the script to the child themes functions file using [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri)

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'child_theme_name_scripts' );
function child_theme_name_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'lektor', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/synteza.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
```

Use [`wp_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) rather than [`init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/init).

Answer (score -1):

if you use child themes, "template_directory" would return the parent theme directory location.
 I use 'CHILD_URL' and 'PARENT_URL' if you just need to print print urls.