# Why isn't is_home() working correctly?

Tags: customization, theme-development, hooks

I put a `if(is_home())` bit in my theme's functions.php and it doesn't seem to work. The function containing this bit is called on init so `is_home` should work already.

Comment: Thanx for tags!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`is_home()` won't work until `wp_query` is run. The earliest hook you can use where is_home will work is `'parse_query'`, but `'template_redirect'` would be better.

Comment: Technically, `'parse_query'` runs before `'wp'` and is the absolute earliest you can check for `is_home()` with any certainty.

Comment: wp() is called after init, so template_redirect is the first hook, for more options and a better view, see: http://toolpress.de/Toolpress_-_Wordpress-3.0-Program-Flow-0.2-2010-06-28.pdf

Comment: You misunderstood me, hakre. `'parse_query'` and `'wp'` are action hooks too, and that's what I was referencing.

Comment: oh, no, not at all. I just wanted to underline what you wrote. I think your answer is just totally right.

Answer (score 2):

To follow up on John's answer:
 Add a call to said function on one of the hooks mentioned by John and hakre.

Add, e.g., the following to your functions.php:

```
<?php
function my_function_name(){
  if(is_home()) do_something();
}

add_action('template_redirect', 'my_function_name');
?>
```

EDIT: I misread your question at first -- it looks like you've got a function encapsulating the code already, it's just that you're firing on the wrong hook. Either break that section out into a separate function and have it fire at template_redirect, etc., or change where you're hooking in the first place.