# wp-admin post.php JavaScript Links Not Working

Tags: admin, wp-admin, javascript, wpdb

I just recently noticed in my backend admin panel none of the dynamic JavaScript links will open or work at all. This includes the 'Edit' links next to Status, Visibility, and Scheduled. Also the slug permalink edit button will not do any Ajax/JavaScript.

Clicking any of the links will just append the hashtag value (ex. **#edit_timestamp**) into my URL. But it appears as though there is no way to update the publishing timestamp or post URL without going through JavaScript. Is this a common issue that others have run into?

I already tried disabling all my plugins which I'm only using 2 - Akismet and Google XML Sitemaps. I also tried switching off my default theme to use Twenty Eleven and TWenty Ten, but still these links will not work. It's very stressful because I can't even write new posts or schedule them to publish in the future without directly editing the database.

Would appreciate any feedback if somebody has seen this problem before! Also let me know if I can clarify anything because I realize this may be confusing.

Comment: What's inside javascript console?  (you shoudl got some js errors isn't it?)

Comment: @CodeMonkey This is actually really strange but if I load the page with the Google Chrome Console window open, all these menus load fine. However if I load the page THEN open the console I get [these errors](http://i.imgur.com/bK0hG.jpg) and the links still will not open. Why do you think having the console open to start will not cause any JavaScript errors? that is the strangest thing to me of all this... I noticed in my admin code there are a bunch of small iframes pointing towards google which appear blank. These are probably related to the X-Frame-Options error but I'm not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should check out the other posts related to this. A lot of times you will have some type of malware in Wordpress coded in PHP which screws with your JS codes. I have seen other threads on stack about similar points.. JavaScript widgets do not move and no ajax edits.

Check out [this stack thread](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1058/loading-external-scripts-in-admin-but-only-for-a-specific-post-type) and also you should clear out any junk files you find inside your theme folder. Or really anything suspicious inside the /wp-includes/ and /wp-content/ directories.

Comment: Yes in truth I actually found that the problem was some type of infected files with PHP eval statements. Either they were overwriting strings in my documents, adding excess JS files to append <iframe> elements to other websites. deleting these files cleared up everything and my backend works perfectly again (: