# Generating CSS Files Dynamically Using PHP Scripts?

Tags: theme-development, css

As part of my efforts to speed up my themes for my clients I am delivering my CSS via a dynamic PHP file. At the end of the called for example `my_theme_css.php`:

This allows me to add Expiry headers to my CSS and JavaScript like so:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 20:00:00 GMT");
header('Content-type: text/css');
?>
```

I then want to allow the user to add thir own custom CSS so I have set the following up:

```
<?php
header("Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 20:00:00 GMT");
header('Content-type: text/css');
?>

p{color:blue;}

/** Custom CSS **/
<?php 
if(get_theme_mod('my_custom_css') != '') {
  $my_custom_css = get_theme_mod('my_custom_css'); 
  echo $my_custom_css; 
}
?>
```

I have then added the applicable theme options. But what I am finding is that `get_theme_mod()` doesn't work due to scope issue (I imagine.) Any suggestions on how to get around this?

I could add the following code:

```
<?php 
if(get_theme_mod('my_custom_css') != '') {
  $my_custom_css = get_theme_mod('my_custom_css'); 
  echo $my_custom_css; 
}
?>
```

Within `<style></style>` tags in the header and that would work fine, expect I don't want the CSS inline, I want it on the main CSS file with the expiry header.

Comment: Wouldn't a static css file be better for performance?  There is also some good advice I got on a similar [question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-do-i-add-css-options-to-my-plugin-without-using-inline-styles) I asked.

Comment: @Chris_O If this was for a few style rules I would say yes but for heavier usage doing it inline means 100's of extra lines downloaded everytime a page is loaded versus one external style sheet with a far future expiry date that can be cached

Comment: *@Ash G:* Provide a static CSS file and setup caching in the Webserver properly. That's my suggestion.

Comment: @hakre This will be used in cases where access at that level on the server is not available or where the end user isn't sufficiently knowledgeable to make those changes. For this reason the code needs to be at the theme level.

Comment: *@Ash G:* If that's the case, that's relying on PHP then, true.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Hi **@Ash G:**

**I didn't follow 100%** where you were specifically having problems so I'm not sure I really can answer your issues point-by-point **but I can explain how to do this from ground up**. And unless what you are doing is a good bit more involved then you mentioned it's a little bit more work than I think you were anticipating but it is still completely doable. And even if I'm covering lots of ground that you already know there's a good chance other's with less knowledge or experience will find this via Google and be helped by it too.

### Bootstrap WordPress with `/wp-load.php`

The first thing we need to do in your `my_theme_css.php` file is bootstrap WordPress' core library functions. The following line of code loads `/wp-load.php`. It uses `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to locate the website's root so you don't have to worry about where you store this file on your server; assuming `DOCUMENT_ROOT` is set correctly as it always should be for WordPress then this will bootstrap WordPress:

```
<?php
include_once("{$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-load.php");
```

So that's the easy part. Next comes the tricky part...

### PHP Scripts Must Handle All Caching Logic

Here's where I'll bet you might have stumbled because I sure did as I was trying to figure out how to answer your question. We are so used to the caching details being handled by the Apache web server that we forget or even don't realize **we have to do all the heavy lifting ourselves** when we load CSS or JS with PHP.

Sure the expiry header may be all we need when we have a proxy in the middle but if the request makes it to the web server and the PHP script just willy-nilly returns content and the *"Ok"* status code well in essence you'll have no caching.

### Returning "200 Ok" or "304 Not Modified"

More specifically our PHP file that returns CSS needs to respond correctly to the ***request*** headers sent by the browser. Our PHP script needs to return the proper status code based upon what those headers contain. If the content needs to be served because it's a first time request or because the content has expired the PHP script should generate all the CSS content and return with a *"200 Ok"*.

On the other hand if we determine based on the cache-related ***request*** headers that the client browser already has the latest CSS we should *not* return any CSS and instead return with a *"304 Not Modified"*. The too lines of code for this are respectively *(of course you'd never use them both one line after another, I'm only showing that way here for convenience)*:

```
<?php 
header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');
header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
```

### Four Flavors of HTTP Caching

Next we need to look at the different ways HTTP can handle caching. The first is what you mention; `Expires`:

- [**Expires**](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html#EXPIRES): This `Expires` header expectz a date in the ([PHP `gmdate()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php)) format of `'D, d M Y H:i:s'` with a `' GMT'` appended (*GMT* stands for *Greenwich Mean Time*.) Theoretically if this header is served the browser and downstream proxies will cache until the specified time passes after which it will start requesting the page again. This is probably the best known of caching headers but evidently not the preferred one to use; [*Cache-Control being the better one*](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/tips.html#SCRIPT). Interestingly in my testing on `localhost` with Safari 5.0 on Mac OS X I was never able to get the browser to respect the `Expires` header; it *always* requested the file again (if someone can explain this I'd be grateful.) Here's the example you gave from above:

> `header("Expires: Thu, 31 Dec 2020 20:00:00 GMT");`

- [**Cache-Control**](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html#CACHE-CONTROL): The `Cache-Control` header is easier to work with than the `Expires` header because you only need to specify the number of time in seconds as `max-age` meaning you don't have to come up with an exact date format in string form that is easy to get wrong. Additionally `Cache-Control` allows several other options such as being able to tell the client to always re-validated the cache using the `mustrevalidate` option and `public` when you want to force caching for normally non-cachable requests (i.e requests via `HTTPS`) and even not cache if that's what you need (i.e. you might want to force a [*a 1x1 pixel ad tracking .GIF*](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html#VALIDATE) not to be cached.) Like `Expires` I was also unable to get this to work in testing (*any help?*) The following example caches for a 24 hour period (60 seconds by 60 minutes by 24 hours):

> `header("Cache-Control: max-age=".60*60*24.", public, must-revalidate");`

- [**Last-Modified** / **If-Modified-Since**](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html#VALIDATE): Then there is the `Last-Modified` response header and If-`Modified-Since` request header pair. These also use the same GMT date format that the `Expires` header use but they do a handshake between client and server. The PHP script needs to send a `Last-Modified` header (which, by the way, you should update only when your user last updates their custom CSS) after which the browser will continue to send the same value back as an `If-Modified-Since` header and it's the PHP script's responsibility to compare the saved value with the one sent by the browser. Here is where the PHP script needs to make the decision between serving a `200 Ok` or a `304 Not Modified`. Here's an example of serving the `Last-Modified` header using the current time (which is *not* what we want to do; see the later example for what we actually need):

> `header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()).'GMT');`

And here is how you'd read the `Last-Modified` returned by the browser via the `If-Modified-Since` header:

> `$last_modified_to_compare = $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE'];`

- [**ETag** / **If-None-Match**](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/how.html#VALIDATE): And lastly there's the `ETag` response header and the `If-None-Match` request header pair. The `ETag` which is really just a token that our PHP sets it to a unique value (typically based on the current date) and sends to the browser and the browser returns it. It the current value is different from what the browser returns your PHP script should regenerate the content an server `200 Ok` otherwise generate nothing and serve a `304 Not Modified`. Here's an example of setting an `ETag` using the current time:

> `header("ETag: " . md5(gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()).'GMT'));`

And here is how you'd read the `ETag` returned by the browser via the `If-None-Match` header:

> `$etag_to_match = $_SERVER['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH'];`

Now that we've covered all that let's look at the actual code we need:

### Serving the CSS file via `init` and `wp_enqueue_style()`

You didn't show this but I figured I would show it for the benefit of others. Here's the function call that tells WordPress to use `my_theme_css.php` for it's CSS. This can be stored in the theme's `functions.php` file or even in a plugin if desired:

```
<?php
add_action('init','add_php_powered_css');
function add_php_powered_css() {
  if (!is_admin()) {
    $version = get_theme_mod('my_custom_css_version',"1.00");
    $ss_dir = get_stylesheet_directory_uri();
    wp_enqueue_style('php-powered-css', 
        "{$ss_dir}/my_theme_css.php",array(),$version);
  }
}
```

There are several points to note:

- **Use of `is_admin()`** to avoid loading the CSS while in the admin (unless you want that...),
- **Use of `get_theme_mod()`** to load the CSS with a default version of `1.00` (more on that in a bit),
- **Use of `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`** to grab the correct directory for the current theme, even if the current theme is a child theme,
- **Use of `wp_enqueue_style()`** to queue the CSS to allow WordPress to load it at the proper time where `'php-powered-css'` is an arbitrary name to reference as a dependency later (*if needed*), and the empty `array()` means this CSS has no dependencies (*although in real world it would often have one or more*), and
- **Use of `$version`**; Probably the most important one, we are telling `wp_enqueue_style()` to add a `?ver=1.00` parameter to the `/my_theme_css.php` URL so that if the version changes the browser will view it as a completely different URL (Much more on that in a bit.)

### Setting `$version` and `Last-Modified` when User Updates CSS

So here's the trick. Every time the user updates their CSS you want to serve the content and not wait until `2020` for everyone's browser cache to timeout, right? Here's a function that combined with my other code will accomplish that. Every time you store CSS updated by the user, use this function or functionality similar to what's contained within:

```
<?php
function set_my_custom_css($custom_css) {
  $new_version = round(get_theme_mod('my_custom_css_version','1.00',2))+0.01;
  set_theme_mod('my_custom_css_version',$new_version);
  set_theme_mod('my_custom_css_last_modified',gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s',time()).' GMT');
  set_theme_mod('my_custom_css',$custom_css);
}
```

The `set_my_custom_css()` function automatically increments the current version by 0.01 (which was just an arbitrary increment value I picked) and it also sets the last modified date to *right now* and finally stores the new custom CSS. To call this function it might be as simple as this *(where `new_custom_css` would likely get assigned via a user submitted `$_POST` instead of by hardcoding as you see here)*:

```
<?php
$new_custom_css = 'body {background-color:orange;}';
set_my_custom_css($new_custom_css);
```

Which brings us to the final albeit significant step:

### Generating the CSS from the PHP Script

Finally we get to see the meat, the actual `my_theme_css.php` file. At a high level it tests both the `If-Modifed-Since`  against the saved `Last-Modified` value and the `If-None-Match` against the `ETag` which was derived from the saved `Last-Modified` value and if neither have changed just sets the header to `304 Not Modifed` and branches to the end.

If however either of those have changed it generates the `Expires`, `Cache-Control`. `Last-Modified` and `Etag` headers as well as a `200 Ok` and indicating that the content type is `text/css`. We probably don't need all those but given how finicky caching can be with different browsers and proxies I figure it doesn't hurt to cover all bases. *(And anyone with more experience with HTTP caching and WordPress please do chime in if I got any nuances wrong.)*

There are a few more details in the following code but I think you can probably work them out on your own:

```
<?php

  $s = $_SERVER;

  include_once("{$s['DOCUMENT_ROOT']}/wp-load.php");

  $max_age = 60*60*24; // 24 hours
  $now = gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()).'GMT';
  $last_modified = get_theme_mod('my_custom_css_last_modified',$now);
  $etag = md5($last_modified);

  if (strtotime($s['HTTP_IF_MODIFIED_SINCE']) >= strtotime($last_modified) || $s['HTTP_IF_NONE_MATCH']==$etag) {
    header('HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified');
  } else {
    header('HTTP/1.1 200 Ok');
    header("Expires: " . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time()+$max_age.'GMT'));
    header("Cache-Control: max-age={$mag_age}, public, must-revalidate");
    header("Last-Modified: {$last_modified}");
    header("ETag: {$etag}");
    header('Content-type: text/css');
    echo_default_css();
    echo_custom_css();
  }
  exit;

function echo_custom_css() {
  $custom_css = get_theme_mod('my_custom_css');
  if (!empty($custom_css))
    echo "\n{$custom_css}";
}

function echo_default_css() {
  $default_css =<<<CSS
body {background-color:yellow;}
CSS;
  echo $default_css;
}
```

So with these three major bits of code; 1.) the `add_php_powered_css()` function called by the `init` hook, 2.) the `set_my_custom_css()` function called by whatever code allows the user to update their custom CSS, and lastly 3.) the `my_theme_css.php` you should pretty much have this licked.

### Further Reading

Aside from those already linked I came across a few other articles that I thought were really useful on the subject so I figured I should link them here:

- [**Cache it! Solve PHP Performance Problems**](http://articles.sitepoint.com/article/caching-php-performance/) - A typical [SitePoint](http://www.sitepoint.com/) Uber-Article; five (5) long pages of all things caching and PHP, covering HTTP and other forms of caching.
- [**CSS Caching Hack**](http://www.stefanhayden.com/blog/2006/04/03/css-caching-hack/) - This is what I did with `$version` but he explains more in-depth than I did.
- [**php: howto control page caching**](http://www.badpenguin.org/php-howto-control-page-caching) - Good details on using HTTP headers with PHP.

### Epilogue:

But I would be remiss to leave the topic without making a closing comments.

#### Expires in `2020`? Probably Too Extreme.

First, I don't really think you want to set `Expires` to the year 2020. Any browsers or proxies that respect `Expires` won't re-request even after you've made many CSS changes. Better to set something reasonable like 24 hours (like I did in my code) but even that will frustrate users for the day during which you make changes in the hardcoded CSS but forget to but the served version number. Moderation in all things?

#### This Might All Be Overkill Anyway!

As I was reading various articles to help me answer your question I came across the following from [Mr. Cache Tutorial](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/) himself, [Mark Nottingham](http://www.mnot.net/personal/):

> The best way to make a script
>   cache-friendly (as well as perform
>   better) is to dump its content to a
>   plain file whenever it changes. The
>   Web server can then treat it like any
>   other Web page, generating and using
>   validators, which makes your life
>   easier. Remember to only write files
>   that have changed, so the
>   Last-Modified times are preserved.

While all this code I wrote it cool and was fun to write (yes, I actually admitted that), [**maybe it's better just to generate a static CSS file every time the user updates their custom CSS**](http://www.web-caching.com/mnot_tutorial/tips.html#SCRIPT) instead, and let Apache do all the heavy lifting like it was born to do? I'm just sayin...

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Mike,Thanks for this. You always give such excellent answers! I was trying to avoid the whole wp_load thing though ( http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/ )

Comment: *@Ash G:* heh. Well that's why yours wasn't working! ;-) `get_theme_mod()` is part of the WordPress API so without `/wp-load.php` you don't get it! And the API is not modular, it's all or nothing. But I'll argue while Otto's is right in general it's not a big a concern if you are caching for 24 hours or longer with `Expires` or `Cache-Control`. And if you really wanted to optimize you could remove the `/wp-load.php` and use raw MySQL calls to replace the `get_theme_mod()` function if you like; it's trivial code, only downside is itbreaks the API's encapsulation of theme mod storage details.

Comment: *@Ash G:* Of course there's always the last part of my answer that I started with *"This Might All Be Overkill Anyway!"*... :-)

Comment: *@AshG*: Oh, and thanks for the compliment. I learn best by teaching others and I'm trying to become expert on everything there is to know about coding for WordPress so that's why I put the effort into the answers. Helping others helps me; that'a a good *win-win*, no? :-)

Comment: to use raw sql calls still requires knowing the database prefix which can't be done without wp-load as well (I believe?) at least if its to be done dynamically (in the case of a theme that is being distributed). That aside I have bookmarked this as  a reference for caching. Thanks!

Comment: Hi *@Ash G*: Well you could use `file_get_contents()` and scan through `/wp-config.php` looking for `$table_prefix` and `DB_HOST`, `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, and `DB_PASSWORD`; that wouldn't be hard code to write nor code with too much overhead (compared to all of `/wp-load.php`) Points to ponder. :) And thanks for the pick and up-vote.

Comment: Is this still the way to go now?

Comment: @Alvaro Pretty much.

Answer (score 0):

Try coding it like:

```
<?php $my_custom_css = get_theme_mod('my_custom_css');
  if(!empty($my_custom_css)) {
    echo $my_custom_css;
  }
?>
```

That should get you around any scope issues with the `get_theme_mod()` function.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This doesn't work though. I don't understand why this would get around the scope issue?

Comment: I don't understand why there would be a scope issue with a function in the first place. But I thought I'd demonstrate the way I've seen similar tasks done in other plugins.