# Include CSS with PHP without including wp-load?

Tags: css, wp-load.php

I have a CSS-file generated from PHP.

**In my file it says...**

```
header("Content-type: text/css");
define('WP_USE_THEMES', false);
include '../../../../wp-load.php';
```

I've read that including wp-load.php like this is not good. Why I do this is to get the environment in there.

What is the "correct" way of doing this?

Comment: can you post your php generated CSS code?

Comment: You are doubling the server load this way. For every page request, WordPress will be loaded twice. Even after using html cache at server side, WordPress will still be loaded for each CSS request. Bad approach! Instead write the CSS file in the directory as per the conditions and then pick it up as a static resource.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## EDIT

Forget my answer below. You could simply use `wp_register_style` and `wp_enqueue_style` described in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1445/how-do-i-add-css-options-to-my-plugin-without-using-inline-styles).

---

You could do it with an additional query variable.

1. Add a new variable to the `$query_vars` array with the `query_vars` filter
2. On the `template_redirect` action, make sure your `custom.php`-css file is included, if the query variable is set.

   ```
   // functions.php
   function wpse26013_add_query_vars(query_vars) {
       $query_vars[] = 'style';
       return $query_vars;
   }
   add_filter('query_vars', 'wpse26013_add_query_vars');

   function wpse26013_include_custom_css() {
       $style = get_query_var('style');

       if($style == 'custom') {
           include_once(get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/custom.php');
           return;
       }
   }
   add_action('template_redirect', 'wpse26013_include_custom_css');
   ```

Then you can add a simple css include in your header file.

```
// header.php
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="<?php bloginfo('stylesheet_url') . '/css/?style=custom'; ?>" />
```

Last but not least, you have to define your custom css file.

```
// custom.php
<?php
header('Content-type: text/css');
header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate");
header('Expires: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', time() + 1209600) . ' GMT');

$options = get_option('webeo');
?>
#header #logo {
    background: url('<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/images/' . $options['header']['site_logo']; ?>') no-repeat;
}
```

You could also get the contents from the css file with the builtin PHP function `file_get_contents()` and print the css directly to the sourcecode.