# 404 error on dynamic stylesheet creation

Tags: 404-error, css

Following this solution to create dynamic css instead of inline css from sorich87 I get an error when requesting the dynamically generated stylesheet. Css is in there but also the default wp error page and a 404 header returned.

Solution I used:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1454

My stylesheet url with 404 error:
http://tegelzetbedrijf.net/wp-content/plugins/wp-google-fonts/googlefonts.css?build=20120126

Any suggestions are highly appreciated!
Thanks
Quokka

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what the error is...it looks like you're outputing text though, not CSS.

Comment: Hi,

I'm outputting css, with  header("Content-type: text/css");
But a 404 error is triggered, I understand why, because the file is not physically available. 

But if anyone knows how to prevent this, that would be awesome!

Thanks!

Comment: View source, you have a lot of HTML in there, CSS files need to be pure CSS. It looks like wordpress is trying to load it as a template or something of that nature.

Comment: Yes I know that, wp is serving the defaul 404 page. With my css in it.  I would like to know how to prevent that and avoid the 404 error from happening. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution you're using to get the stylesheets onto the page is a terrible method. Wordpress provides the enqueue functions specifically to do what you're trying to do. [The codex page on `wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) explains exactly what you need to do. If you would like to add a dynamic version, there is a parameter for that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'll digg into that!! For the meantime if just added the css in my stylesheet manually :)