# Why is home (a lot) slower than other pages?

Tags: optimization, performance

I'm trying to tune a wordpress website which suffers slow loading times, and I found out that the home page seems to take a lot more time to load. It's not due to content because I'm just considering the time it takes for the base request to end (viewable via firebug in firefox).

Also I tried copying the index.php code in a custom page, and the same exact code loads in about 1 sec while the main home loads in about 7. I noticed that single pages loaded faster, and at first I thought it was due to the difference in content, but after this test I'm not sure what's causing this.

Is there much stuff that wordpress does behind the scenes only for the main index? Is there any other way to explain this situation and, more importantly, fix it so that the home page loads faster?

**UPDATE -- DIRTY SOLUTION**

After a lot of blind tries, I created a new page called home which uses `index.php` as custom template (not a copy, the same file). I redirected any call to the base path to it (via wordpress' internal rewrite) and I have the same homepage as before, just loaded in 1/6th of the time. While I'm happy with the result, I'd really like to understand what's going on.

**ANOTHER UPDATE**

So the point seems to be that I cannot use a dynamic (in wordpress' sense) page with this site, it only works fine with a custom "static" page where I insert content via various functions, the normal Loop makes the home either very slow (with high memory limit) or just blank (low memory limit, script fails).

As suggested in [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4574/how-can-i-create-an-alternative-home-page), I created a static home linked to a custom page and it works fine. I also created a blog page (again with a custom template) which also works fine (where "fine" means it shows my empty test page containing just one word and no code) **unless** I specify it as "Posts page" in admin -> Reading settings. In other words it looks like as soon as wordpress sees a dynamic page (the one that's supposed to hold The main Loop) it does something very heavy which eats up a lot of ram.

Still looking for the cause of this, I can work around it but I'd really like to understand what the problem is.

Edit: added bounty

More info: I tried disabling all plugins, wordpress is updated to the latest version.

**FURTHER EDIT: TABLE INDEXES**

wp_posts:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`ID`),
KEY `type_status_date` (`post_type`,`post_status`(1),`post_date`,`ID`),
KEY `post_status_date_gmt` (`post_status`(1),`post_date_gmt`),
KEY `post_date` (`post_date`),
KEY `post_date_gmt` (`post_date_gmt`),
KEY `post_parent` (`post_parent`),
KEY `post_name` (`post_name`),
KEY `post_status` (`post_status`),
KEY `post_author` (`post_author`),
FULLTEXT KEY `post_related` (`post_name`,`post_content`),
FULLTEXT KEY `post_content` (`post_content`,`post_title`),
```

wp_term_relationships:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`object_id`,`term_taxonomy_id`),
KEY `term_taxonomy_id` (`term_taxonomy_id`)
```

wp_term_taxonomy:

```
PRIMARY KEY  (`term_taxonomy_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `term_id_taxonomy` (`term_id`,`taxonomy`),
KEY `taxonomy` (`taxonomy`)
```

Comment: @kemp - Unless I'm missing it you haven't included a link that to home page so we can see it for ourselves. Can you do that?

Comment: Also, please add these profiling tools to your site: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612 so as to allow to view: `http://example.com?debug=sql`

Comment: @Denis tried that, can't seem to get any output. I get a blank page and the occasional internal server error with this message in the log: `Premature end of script headers: index.php`

Comment: @kemp did you delete the cache contents and  retried the tests with 2 identical pages (dynamic / static) ?

Comment: Duh, I just noted that your URLs use a verbose permalink structure. What happens when you use one of the suggested date/name based structures, e.g. /YYYY/MM/slug/?

Comment: @edelwater: yes the dynamic test page now contains only the words `BLOG PAGE` and nothing else, no cache is active. Still fails even with a 9 byte plain text template.

Comment: Have you added the indexes I suggested from within PhpMyAdmin?

Comment: @Denis: yes, I have. Same exact behavior: blog page shows up UNLESS it's set as "posts page" in reading options.

Comment: k... after installing my above-mentioned profiling tools, head to your blog page's template, and add `return;` statements to see what's happening. Also, can you confirm you've a large enough amount of php memory around? Your 500 error would typically be something related to php-suexec, but blank screens are more frequently related to the php memory limit in php.ini.

Comment: Have you tried adding return; statements in your blog home page's template file to know where things time out?

Comment: No, because as I said **it does not depend on the template**, the same exact problem happens even if the blog page's template contains one word or even **nothing**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After almost 4 years I got back on this and finally found the problem. Turns out the site had a lot of articles ALL marked as sticky. Due to the unbelievably dumb way wordpress uses to mark sticky posts (a serialized array in wp_options), the main loop of the dynamic home page took an incredibly long time. Clearing the `sticky_posts` field in the table fixed the problem.

Answer (score 8):

I beg to differ with the previous two comments.

Using a static home page results in WP using an index scan on the posts table's primary key, vs an (oh so occasional) index scan on post_date, status or post_parent in the posts table.

In essence, the home page is dead slow because of the poor database design in WP. The schema has ludicrous multicolumn indexes on the taxonomy tables which MySQL simply ignores once you've a meaningful amount of posts. The fact that we're using a table too much for taxonomies doesn't help either.

In the database, safely add indexes on:

```
CREATE INDEX extra_posts ON posts (post_type,post_status,post_date DESC)
CREATE INDEX extra_term_rel ON term_relationships(term_taxonomy_id,object_id)
CREATE INDEX extra_term_tax ON term_taxonomy(taxonomy,term_taxonomy_id,term_id)
```

It won't be perfect, but at least WP will be able to use index-based nested loop plans on your front page...

Oh, and... if you're using any kind of custom post type on your front page, you also need to add:

```
posts(post_status,post_date DESC)
```

Else no index will be used at all for the main query because of the OR clauses.

Comment: @Denis can you please review the indexes? I updated the question as they wouldn't fit in a comment. Also, can 13.200 posts be considered just too many? What's also strange from my point of view is that the normal loop in categories pages work perfectly fine.

Comment: 13200 rows is very few in a database unless they're poorly queried. My dev site with a couple of odd posts reads the whole disk page and quicksorts the result in no meaningful time. My live site, by contrast, has a bit over 1000 posts and php takes in the order of 50ms to retrieve the front page's posts. To put this in perspective, my PgSQL dev site pulls top-10 rows out of a few hundred thousands in 20ms...

Comment: Re your current indexes: type_status_date is so wide that MySQL usually prefers to use post_status or post_date. post_status_date_gmt/post_date_gmt get used internally for very specific queries. Usually the first in my experience. post_parent/post_name are used when querying for hierarchical types; the first would benefit from having the post_type prepended in there to retrieve root pages quickly. post_author is useful for author pages, and in the admin area. For the front end's author pages, this would be more ideal: (post_author, post_type, post_status, post_date DESC).

Comment: Continuing... term_tax (object_id,term_taxonomy_id) is good to get tags/cats/etc from posts. Last I checked, none of the other indexes on terms get used. My above-mentioned extra_term_tax allows to actually get the terms using an index, and extra_term_rel would allow to fetch posts that match a term.

Comment: @Denis -- great answer here... I just wanted to ask you if your proposed solution to his problem is something you implement on your wordpress sites by default?

Comment: No, I don't. The proper DB indexes depend on what you're doing with your DB in practice... If you're frequently querying post_parent/post_name, you need an index on it; if a meta is more of your thing, you need an index on it... it really depends on what you're doing. Else, yeah, those indexes, I occasionally add through plugins depending on what I'm developing.

Answer (score 5):

By default there isn't any difference for performance of home page. There is however a possibility that some plugin does something slow on that page alone.

There are plenty plugins to profile WP performance. I usually use [WP Tuner](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wptuner/) but it seems to be broken for latest WP version, so I have no immediate replacement to suggest.

Simplest way is packing template full of time/memory markers.

```
printf(  '%d queries in %.3f seconds, using %.2fMB memory', get_num_queries(), timer_stop( 0, 3 ), memory_get_peak_usage() / 1024 / 1024 );
```

It's crude but often allows to pinpoint location where slowdown occurs.

Comment: Rarst is right. You likely have a plugin or widget that is only running on the homepage and is doing long queries about something (like maybe checking for a category or something?)

Comment: @Jeremy: but that doesn't explain why an exact copy of the home loads faster under another page name.

Comment: @Rarst: thanks for the suggestion but I can't seem to get it working right. I see the report on the admin page but nothing on the regular ones. Might depend on the fact that wordpress is bridged with vbulletin and the plugin doesn't recognize me as a logged in admin

Comment: It may be exact code of page's code but it's not exact copy of environment. Conditional tags are very basic WordPress code technique - home page and regular page can be identical in code, but conditional tags will return different values and so different code might fire on hooks. | Not working - you mean plugin or snippet?

Comment: There are no conditional tags, and the pages rendered in the browser are identical. By not working I'm referring to the plugin: doc is quite lacking so I assumed WP tuner put its info at the bottom of every page if you are logged as admin -- but I only see that in wp-admin

Comment: There are always conditional tags. Things like `wp_head()` launch hooks that can (and often do) process numerous functions. Template file is only rough outline of which code gets run, there is a lot more under wraps. | As in original answer WP Tuner has compatibility issues with latest WP version (you do run up to date version, right?) so it's better to look up alternative.

Comment: Kemp: Try disabling all your plugins and see if the difference is still there. If its gone enable them one by one. Another way of testing this would be to install a brand new site with not plugins and run your theme on it, see if the home page still takes longer.

Comment: Tried without plugins, and with another theme too. I also tried **deleting** the plugins directory.

Comment: Also check drop-in plugin files. There might be some cache-related leftover in there `/wp-admin/plugins.php?plugin_status=dropins`. Other than that I am out of ideas. If it isn't specific to theme or plugins the only options left are modified core or database issues.

Answer (score 0):

If the home page is taking that long to load, most likely you have a plugin or a function in the theme that is making a remote request some time when the home page is rendering.

I would do a recursive search through your wp-content directory for calls to 'wp_remote_' to look for any functions that may be causing this.

Comment: It must be something that wordpress does *before* loading the template, because it's not due to the code of the page.

Comment: The code might not be on the page itself, but functions like `wp_head()` call action hooks that plug-ins can use to call secondary functionality.  That's why *@prettyboymp* suggested a search through the entire `wp-content` directory and why *@Jeremy Clarke* recommended disabling all plug-ins above.

Comment: Yes but **the same exact page** works fine called as "static", it hangs only when called as "dynamic".

Answer (score 0):

At first, check the quereis of WOrdPress and the included images, scripts and stylesheets. You can check the queries with the plugin [Debug Queries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/) and you become more information about your install and mistakes with the plugin [Debug Objects](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-objects/).