# Who are the most trusted plugin developers?

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, plugin-recommendation

*Note: Please vote on the question, and any answers you find useful by clicking on the UP arrow on the left hand side of the question or answer.*

There are so many plugins out there. Whose plugins can we always trust?

Please share a list of completely reliable plugin authors, along with links to their plugins pages.

This question is modeled on [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file)

Comment: As much as I'm in favor of a kind of "reliable/trustworthy plugin developers" list ... this is still somewhat subjective.  Some of the best plugin developers don't list their systems in the WP repository.  You might have a **very** reliable developer with only 1 plugin in the repo and a still competent but less-skilled developer with 30 ... also, if you have no need to use those specific systems, how will knowing the developer is trustworthy make any kind of difference?

Comment: I think it's better to have list of great developers, rather than not to. Yes, it's subjective and can't possibly be complete. Still will be good starting point when looking for good plugins to use.

Comment: IMHO voting on the answers would make much more sense if it would be one developer per answer. As seen in mentioned thread [best of functions.php](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file) and alike.

Answer (score 9):

### Alex King

- [Website](http://alexking.org/)
- [WordPress.org Profile](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/alexkingorg/)

### Mark Jaquith

[image]

- [Website](http://coveredwebservices.com/)
- [WordPress Profiles](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/markjaquith)

### Otto

[image]

- [Website](http://ottopress.com/)
- [WordPress.org Profile](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/Otto42/)

### Stephen Rider

- [Blog](http://striderweb.com/blog/)
- [Google Code (Strider Core)](http://code.google.com/p/strider-core/)
- [WordPress.org Profile](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/strider72)

Comment: Even if there's nothing technically wrong with it, I think it's at least disingenuous to include yourself on that list. Also, If they don't have a WordPress.org Profile, they shouldn't be on this list.

Comment: In the interest of fairness, I've removed myself from the list ... though I'd still argue that you can be a quality plugin developer and *not* have plugins listed in the WP repository.  Stephen Rider's code is referenced frequently in other systems and his Strider Core framework is used in several plugins that *are* hosted in the repository.

Comment: PS Thanks for finding his WP.org profile ... I just couldn't locate it because, really, he's better known for posting stuff in Trac, on Google Code, and on his own site than he is on WP.org.

Answer (score 8):

### Justin Tadlock

- [blog](http://justintadlock.com/)
- [Hybrid](http://themehybrid.com/) (theme/framework)
- [DevPress](http://devpress.com/) (theme(s), plugins)
- [repository](http://profiles.wordpress.org/greenshady/)

### Joost "Yoast" de Valk

[image]

- [blog](http://yoast.com/)
- [repository](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/joostdevalk/)

### scribu

[image]

- [blog](http://scribu.net/)
- [repository](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/scribu)

### Automattic

[image]

Proverbial from the horse's mouth. :)

- [repository](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/automattic/)
- [plugins used on wordpress.com](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/tags/wordpresscom)

Answer (score 5):

### [Alex M (Viper007Bond)](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/viper007bond/) (no.1 in terms of number)

[image]

### [hakre](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/hakre/)

[image]

### [Alex King](http://profiles.wordpress.org/users/alexkingorg/)

Comment: You have the same link for the first and third items.

Answer (score 5):

Not directly answering the question, but I've set up a Google Custom Search Engine just to find reliable answers to my WP questions, using most of these authors as the source sources. I add more as I find someone reliable and knowledgeable.

Check it out here:  [Wordpress Developers Custom Search Engine](http://www.google.com/cse/home?cx=002157635966454377808%3A_-i17w7z4d0)

Ones that I have on it that are missing from this list are:

### [Andrew Nacin](http://www.andrewnacin.com)

[image]

### [Vladimir Prelovac](http://www.prelovac.com)

### [Joseph Scott](http://josephscott.org/)

[image]

### [Denis de Bernardy](http://www.semiologic.com/)

[image]