# How to display SQL query that ran in query?

Tags: query, code, sql

I have come across a function before that displayed the exact SQL code that was used.
In a loop for example, but can't remember.

Can anybody tell me that function?

Answer (score 165, accepted):

Hi **@Keith Donegan:**

If I understand your question correctly I think this is what you are looking for?

```
<?php echo $GLOBALS['wp_query']->request; ?>
```

`$wp_query` is a global variable that contains the current query run by the loop. If you run the above code  anytime while the loop is still active or even right after the loop it should give you the SQL from the loop. Just make sure you inspect it before letting something else run that uses `query_posts()` again.

Comment: How to get queries of `$wpdb`? `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->request` not working

Comment: Works even on custom query,
`$my_query = new WP_Query([ /* ...some args... */ ]);` => `$my_query->request`

Comment: it's very helpful

Answer (score 82):

If you ran a query based on `WP_Query`, it's this:

```
$customPosts = new WP_Query($yourArgs);
echo "Last SQL-Query: {$customPosts->request}";
```

Answer (score 27):

See this answer: [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612)

Then add ?debug=sql to any WP URL, and it'll output the full list of queries that were run. (And yes, it's scary...)

Answer (score 27):

If you are only interested in Loops this is what I usually use:

```
add_filter( 'posts_request', 'dump_request' );

function dump_request( $input ) {

    var_dump($input);

    return $input;
}
```