# Sort on meta value but include posts that don't have one

Tags: order, pre-get-posts

I've been modifying the built in WP search using the `pre_get_posts` filter, allowing the user to sort the posts (including a bunch of custom post types) by different fields.

The problem I'm having though is that when I tell WP to sort by a meta value it will exclude all posts that don't have that meta value set. This causes the number of results to change if you change sorting from say "Price" to "Date" because "Posts" don't have "Price" set but "Items" do.

This is not what I want, so I'd like to know if there's a way to include ALL posts - even those that lack the meta value I'm sorting on - and put the one's without the value last.

I know how to sort on more than one field but that doesn't help.

Thanks

Seems I'm not the only one with this question: [Way to include posts both with & without certain meta_key in args for wp_query?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28409/way-to-include-posts-both-with-without-certain-meta-key-in-args-for-wp-query) but there's no solution there.

**Update**

I've tried the answer but not sure if I understood correctly, here's what I have right now:

```
<?php
function my_stuff ($qry) {
    $qry->set('meta_query', array(array(
        'key' => 'item_price', 
        'value' => '', 
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    )));

    $qry->set('orderby', 'meta_value date'); # Sorting works with meta_value as well as meta_value_num - I've tried both
    $qry->set('order', 'ASC DESC');
    $qry->set('meta_key', 'item_price');
}
```

The meta value is a number (it is used to store a price as the name suggests)

**Update 2**

I've commented out the order-stuff and all I have now is this:

```
<?php
$qry->set('meta_query', array(array(
    'key' => 'item_price', 
    'value' => '', 
    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
)));
```

With this code the query seems to return all posts that don't have the `item_price` key and none of the posts that have it. I.E. the problem is now reversed.

If I add in the order-code as well I get 0 results.

Edit: *...three years later...* :P I had this issue again. I tried all the answers given and none work. Not sure why some people seem to think they work but they don't work for me at least.

The solution I ended up with is using the `save_post` filter - making sure all posts have the custom field I wish to sort on. It's a bit annoying I have to do it, but at as long as you do it early on you'll likely have no issues.

In this case I was building a "view counter" on posts and wanted users to be able to sort on the most read posts. Again, posts that have never been viewed (I guess that's pretty unlikely - but still) disappeared when sorting on the view count. I added this bit of code to make sure all posts have a view count:

```
add_action('save_post', function ($postId) {
    add_post_meta($postId, '_sleek_view_count', 0, true);
});
```

Comment: Please show us your code. Makes it easier to answer.

Comment: First: `meta_query` and `tax_query` are **always** an `array( array() )` as they combine multiple arrays. Second - as mentioned in my answer - you need to use `meta_value_num` for numbers. It might as well be needed to actually define the `meta_value_num` (see `WP_Query`-Codex page entry). Last, it doesn't make sense to `order` in `ASC` **and** `DESC` direction. That's not possible. The space delimiter only works for `orderby` and you can't tell it to sort the first `ASC` and the second `DESC`. That's what `posts_clauses` filter is for.

Comment: And make sure that your `meta_value_num` entries are **real** numbers. Seen it too often that someone states that it's a number, but in fact saving it as a string in the database.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I will try this and get back to you. The reason for `ASC DESC` is so that it sorts on the `meta_value` in `ASC` and the `date` in `DESC`, as far as I can tell it works.

Comment: Also, the actual sorting works fine. The only problem is that posts (or custom post types) without the meta value aren't displayed. (In regards to `meta_value_num`)

Comment: To clarify, are you wanting to include posts both with a certain metavalue and posts that do not have that metavalue set?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee that is correct. Some of my custom post types HAVE this value set. Some don't. And the built in post types (like POST and PAGE) do not. So whenever I try to sort on that custom field only posts WITH the custom field show up.

Comment: I've seen questions similar to this before, @G.M. has a good answer, but you must show all results on the same page, so if that doens't work for you, then you either show only posts with the meta_key or posts without the meta_key, not both. [Here's the post I'm referring to](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138781/order-by-optional-meta-key).

Comment: Oh ok thanks. This was for a project I've since long finished but I'll keep this in mind for next time. Although, I _would_ prefer to keep using the normal "WP loop" with the normal pagination...

Comment: I've opened a trac ticket to possibly add a solution to the core query classes that would make this kind of thing possible: https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/42907

Comment: @powerbuoy please see my answer for a solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's two possible solutions to this:

### 1. All posts have meta

The best solution I have found here is to give the rest of the posts/products an item price of 0. You can do this manually, or loop through all the posts and if the price is empty then update it.

To make this manageable in the future you can hook into `save_post` and give them a value when they are first added (only if it's blank).

### 2. Multiple Queries

You could run the first query as you're doing and store the IDs of the posts returned. You could then run another query for all posts and orderby date, **excluding** the IDs return from the first query.

You can then print out the two results separately order and you'll get the desired results.

Comment: Three years later and I had the same issue again :P Had to use the `save_post` method (I've updated my question with the code I used).

Comment: This is possible without having to use hooks or run multiple queries. See my answer.

Comment: You should have shown code examples.

Answer (score 22):

Easy Peasy, just tested 2018, using in production currently.

**Update 2022: Modified so that the `NOT_EXISTS` query comes before the `EXISTS` query, and clarifies the effect that multiple keys has on the `orderby` clause.**

```
$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    array(
        'key' => 'custom_meta_key', 
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'custom_meta_key', 
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),
) );
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value title' );
```

This checks for all items with and without the meta key, with no value specified. the meta query provides the key for the orderby reliably. It has been tested. The `orderby` clause's `meta_value`/`meta_value_num` will use the last key in the chain.

### Practical example

```
/**
 * Modifies query before retrieving posts. Sets the 
 * `meta_query` and `orderby` param when no `orderby` 
 * param is set, (default ordering).
 * 
 * @param   WP_Query  $query  The full `WP_Query` object.
 * @return  void
 */
function example_post_ordering( $query ) {
    
    // if not in wp-admin, 
    // and the query is the main query, 
    // and the query is not a singular query, 
    // and the query does not have an orderby param set...
    // Note: check for post types, etc. here as desired.
    if ( ! is_admin() 
    && $query->is_main_query() 
    && ! $query->is_singular() 
    && empty( $query->get( 'orderby' ) ) ) {
        
        // Setting just `meta_key` is not sufficient, as this 
        // will ignore posts that do not yet, or never will have 
        // a value for the specified key. This meta query will 
        // register the `meta_key` for ordering, but will not 
        // ignore those posts without a value for this key.
        $query->set( 'meta_query', array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key' => 'custom_meta_key', 
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            ),
            array(
                'key' => 'custom_meta_key', 
                'compare' => 'EXISTS'
            ),
        ) );

        // Order by the meta value, then by the title if multiple 
        // posts share the same value for the provided meta key.
        // Use `meta_value_num` if the meta values are numeric.
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value title' );
    }

}

add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'example_post_ordering', 10 );
```

This will order posts by `custom_meta_key` by default, and will not ignore posts without a value for that key.

Comment: Just from reading the code, all that seems to do is get posts which have `custom_meta_key` and get posts whick _don't_ have `custom_meta_key`. Feel free to include an actual working example with sorting.

Comment: You are right, that is all it is doing, but the line below is responsible for ordering by meta_value (of the meta key being queried). `$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value title' );` (Order by meta value, then by title when multiple posts have the same value for the meta key). This should be done in the `pre_get_posts` hook, using the passed in `$query` variable. Keep in mind the question asked was how to order by meta value, while not ignoring posts that do not have a value for that meta key.

Comment: @powerbuoy See updated practical example

Comment: Alright I'll give it a go next time I'm facing this problem.

Comment: Worked for me in a custom `get_posts()` call to shove posts with `_featured` meta to to the top, then order by date after that. Thanks!

Comment: This only worked for me when reversing the order of NOT EXISTS and EXISTS.  It would work, but the orderby would be ignored.

Comment: @mikemike thanks for that info, switching around made this work for me

Comment: @mikemike copy that - I just made this update above.

Answer (score 11):

This method will return all of the posts including those with and without the requested `meta_key`, but it will do weird things when ordering.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_stuff');
function my_stuff ($qry) {
    $qry->set(
        'meta_query',
        array(
            'relation' => 'OR', # Matches to this meta_query should be added to those matching the 'meta_key' query
            array(
                'key' => 'item_price', 
                'value' => 'bug #23268', 
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
            )
        )
    );

    $qry->set('orderby', 'meta_value date'); # Sorting works with meta_value as well as meta_value_num - I've tried both
    $qry->set('order', 'ASC DESC');
    $qry->set('meta_key', 'item_price');
}
```

I found this by fiddling around with all the different answers to this question and analyzing [the generated SQL](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/4818/11518) through trial and error. It seems that setting `array('meta_query' => array('relation' => 'OR'))` outputs an appropriate `LEFT JOIN` instead of `INNER JOIN` that is necessary to include posts missing the metadata. Specifying the `NOT EXISTS` prevents the `WHERE` clause from filtering out posts lacking the meta field. For this particular `WP_Query`, the generated SQL is (indentation/newlines added):

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
    wp_posts.ID
    FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id)
    INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id
    LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mt1 ON (wp_posts.ID = mt1.post_id AND mt1.meta_key = 'item_price')
    WHERE 1=1
    AND ( wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id IN (2) )
    AND wp_posts.post_type = 'post'
    AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
        OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private')
    AND (wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'item_price'
        -- Oh look, here we give SQL permission to choose a random
        -- row from wp_postmeta when this particular post is missing
        -- 'item_price':
        OR  mt1.post_id IS NULL )
    GROUP BY wp_posts.ID
    ORDER BY wp_postmeta.meta_value,wp_posts.post_date DESC
    LIMIT 0, 10
```

The result is a listing of all the posts with meta_value of `item_price` and those missing `item_price`. All of the posts with `item_price` will be ordered correctly relative to each other, but **posts missing `item_price` will use some random *other* meta value** (say, `_edit_last` which seems to be `1` quite often in my database or some other internal wordpress metadata that is completely arbitrary) for its `wp_postmeta.meta_value` in the `ORDER BY` clause. So, while this method is close and may appear to work for certain data, it is broken. So, all I can say is, if your `item_price` values happen to not conflict with the random meta fields MySQL chooses for the posts missing `item_price`, this might work fine for you. If all you need is a guarantee that your posts with `item_price` are correctly ordered relative to each other without regard for the ordering of other posts, it may be OK. But I think this is just a shortcoming in wordpress. Please correct me, I hope I’m wrong and there’s a way to address this ;-).

It seems that for the `INNER JOIN wp_postmeta`, MySQL is choosing a random row from among multiple `postmeta` rows associated with the post when the `meta_key` is missing from the given post. From an SQL perspective, we need to figure out how to tell wordpress to output `ORDER BY mt1.meta_value`. This column is properly `NULL` when our requested `meta_key` is missing, unlike `wp_postmeta.meta_value`. If we could do that, SQL would sort these `NULL` (missing entries) before any other value, giving us a well-defined order: first come all the posts missing the particular postmeta field, second come the posts having the field. But that is the whole problem: `'orderby' => 'meta_value'` can only refer to `'meta_key' => 'item_price'` *and* the unaliased `wp_postmeta` is always an `INNER JOIN` instead of ever a `LEFT JOIN`, meaning `wp_postmeta.meta_value` and `wp_postmeta.meta_key` can *never* be `NULL`.

So I guess I have to say that this isn’t possible with wordpress’s built-in `WP_Query` as it is now documented (in wordpress-3.9.1). Bother. So if you actually need this to work correctly, you probably [need to hook into wordpress elsewhere and modify the generated SQL directly](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/141367/11518).

Comment: Looks very promising! I will try this next time I have this issue. I'd like to give you the answer right now, but would prefer to confirm it works for me first.

Comment: This kept everything from showing up for me. Nothing showed after implementing this.

Comment: @Jake Yea same here. Had this issue again today and tried this. Returns 0 results.

Comment: What version of wordpress are you guys using? I think this post describes how to use an internal, undocumented API which is not supported by wordpress and so probably only works if you’re on wordpress-3.9.1 or not too many versions beyond that.

Answer (score 9):

The problem that everyone here is having has to do with the order of the meta queries. In order to sort correctly, you will need to put the "NOT EXISTS" query **before** the "EXISTS" query.

The reason for this is because WordPress uses the meta_value of the last "LEFT JOIN" statement in the "ORDER BY" clause.

For example:

```php
$pageQuery = new WP_Query([
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        ['key' => 'item_price', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'], // this comes first!
        ['key' => 'item_price', 'compare' => 'EXISTS'],
    ],
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'page',
    'posts_per_page' => 10,
]);
```

Answer (score 3):

I also encountered a similar problem and the following solution helped me:

```
$args = array(
'post_type' => 'kosh_products',
'posts_per_page' => -1,
'meta_query' => array(
    'relation' => 'OR',
    'category_sort_order' => array(
        'key' => '_sort_order',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS'
    ),
    'category_sort_order_not_exists' => array(
        'key' => '_sort_order',
        'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
    ), 
),
'orderby' => array( 
    'category_sort_order' => 'ASC',
    'date' => 'ASC'
));
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
```

I found a description on WordPress Codex with title "**'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's**": https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think I have a solution.

You can use two `meta_key`s, one that all posts have `(like "_thumbnail_id")`, and the `meta_key` you wish use as filter.

So your args:

```
$qry->set(
    'meta_query',
    array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'item_price', 
            'value' => '', 
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'item_price', 
            'value' => '', 
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        )
    )
);

$qry->set('orderby', 'meta_value date'); # Sorting works with meta_value as well as meta_value_num - I've tried both
$qry->set('order', 'ASC DESC');
$qry->set('meta_key', 'item_price');
```

Comment: THe problem here is the empty string comparison, remove it and it works `'value' => '', ` also second compare should be `NOT EXISTS` and the last set instruction is not required

Answer (score 1):

If suitable, you can add a default meta value each time a post is saved or updated, if the meta value does no exists.

```
function addDefaultMetaValue($post_id) {
    add_post_meta($post_id, 'item_price', 0, true);
}
add_action('save_post', 'addDefaultMetaValue');
```

If you are using a custom post type, replace the `add_action('save_post', 'addDefaultMetaValue');` by `add_action('save_post_{post_type}', 'addDefaultMetaValue');` e.g. `add_action('save_post_product', 'addDefaultMetaValue');`

Answer (score 1):

I had the problem by myself for numeric meta values and pointed out that it the order of the query is also important. For me the `NOT EXISTS` query has to be the first one.

Example:

```
$query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
$query->set( 'meta_query', [
    'relation' => 'OR',
    [ 'key' => 'your_meta_name', 'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' ],
    [
        'key' => 'your_meta_name',
        'compare' => 'EXISTS',
    ],
] );
```

Also important in order to get the right direction for numeric values is the general `’orderby’` to be set to `’meta_value_num’`. Otherwise you have strange results for numeric values, e. g.:

1, 2, 20, 21, 3, 4, 5 …

Instead of:

1, 2, 3, 4, 5 … 20, 21

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question but none of the answers were robust enough for me to use and be happy with the results.  The solution below still uses `WP_Query`, but manipulates the join and order by statements.

It makes use of a MySQL function called `ORDER BY IF`, to allow you to effectively run logic during your ORDER BY statement.  This is important because the other solutions here just lump the results with no value either at the front or end of the list, which is useless when you're trying to order by 2 keys.

In the below example I have a CPT of 'businesses'.  I want them all ordered by title but any with `is_premium` should come first.  I've commented the code so you can see what's going on where.

```
<?php
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : 1;
$args = [
    'post_type' => 'business',
    'posts_per_page' => 12,
    'meta_query' => [
        'relation' => 'OR',
        [
            'key' => 'is_premium', 
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' // NOT EXISTS first is important
        ],
        [
            'key' => 'is_premium', 
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ],
    ]
    ,
    'orderby' => [
        'meta_value' => 'DESC', // This is the is_premium field
        'title' => 'ASC',
    ],
    'paged' => $paged
];

// Add our own join to the query
function custom_join($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $join .= $wpdb->prepare(
        ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' cpm ON cpm.post_id = ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID AND cpm.meta_key = %s'
        , 'is_premium' );
    }

    return $join;
}
add_filter('posts_join','custom_join');

// Add our own order by to the query
function custom_orderby($orderby_statement){
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // Here we order by the meta_value ONLY is it's 1, otherwise ignore it for that order statement, which 
        // means it'll be ordered by the next statement (title), the same as the other results
        $orderby_statement = "IF(cpm.meta_value = 1, 1, 0) DESC, wp_posts.post_title ASC ";
    }

    return $orderby_statement;
}
add_filter('posts_orderby','custom_orderby', 10, 2 ); 

// Query
$business = new WP_Query( $args );

// Remove the filters
remove_filter('posts_orderby','custom_orderby');
remove_filter('posts_join','custom_join');
```

Answer (score 1):

The OR meta query combining `NOT EXISTS` and `EXISTS` works but it caused a slow query.

This solution works a lot faster.

The main key was in the SQL order by clause:
`order by YOUR_FIELD is NULL, YOUR_FIELD`

```
add_filter('posts_orderby', function (string $orderby, WP_Query $query) {
    if ('MY_CUSTOM_SORT' === $query->get('orderby')) {
        $orderby = "mta.meta_value is NULL, mta.meta_value ='', mta.meta_value ASC";
    }
    return $orderby;
}, 10, 2);

add_filter('posts_join', function (string $join, WP_Query $query) {
    if ('MY_CUSTOM_SORT' === $query->get('orderby')) {
        $join .= " LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta AS mta ON ( wp_posts.ID = mta.post_id AND mta.meta_key = 'SOME_META_KEY')";
    }
    return $join;
}, 10, 2);
```

And in your WP_Query args:

```
$args['orderby'] = 'MY_CUSTOM_SORT';
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a possible `orderby` value of `meta_value` for that.

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'meta_key'   => 'your_keys_name',
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
         'key'     => 'your_meta_key',
         'value'   => '',
         'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS',
         // 'type'    => 'CHAR',
    ) )
) );
```

If you got numeric values, just use `meta_value_num` instead.

*Disclaimer:* This is not tested, but it *should* work. Point is that you need to specify your `meta_key` and `key` values. Else you can't compare against non-existing values, which should make it possible to query both sorts of posts. It's some kind of hack-ish, but as long as it works...

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please check my updated question, I'm not sure I understood you correctly.

Comment: I still haven't made this work so if you have a solution I'd love to know what I'm doing wrong. Also, I set a bounty on SO if you want to claim it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17016770/wordpress-order-by-meta-value-if-it-exists-else-date/17183618

Comment: Two things. `'your_keys_name'` and `'your_meta_key'` should both be the same string instead of distinct, otherwise it looks like you’ve misunderstood the question. Secondly, I tested this on my local setup and it excludes any posts where the key exists (through the `meta_query`) and excludes any posts where the key is missing (through `meta_key`) resulting in no posts showing. However, this answer is a step toward [something that words](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/111242/11518) at least ;-).

Comment: Oh, interestingly, this answer does work if you just add `'relation' => 'OR'` to `meta_query`. Wacky stuff o_o.

Comment: @binki Just file an [edit] to my question and change the bits you think should be changed. This is a community driven site :)

Comment: @kaiser, I did more fiddling around, even testing, and came up with a small monologue. I assume [my new answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/156381/11518) is appropriate place to store my ramblings in ;-).

Answer (score 0):

I think what @kaiser was trying to do was to tell the query to return all posts that have that meta key by applying a sort of dummy *where condition* to **not** filter any of those posts. So if you know **all** the values your custom fields can take are x,y,z you could say "WHERE meta_key *IN(x,y,z)*" but the idea is you can avoid that problem all together by saying *!= ('')*:

```
$query = new WP_Query( array ( 
    'orderby'    => 'meta_value_num',
    'order'      => 'DESC',
    'meta_query' => array( array(
         'key'     => 'item_price',
         'value'   => '',
         'compare' => '!=',
    ) )
) );
```

Also not tested but feels like it's worth a try :-).

Comment: Can't really test this right now, but pretty sure that will only return posts where item_price is set and it's not ''.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up getting around this with a bit of a hack (IMHO), but it did the job for me in my case.

You can hook into the filters [posts_join_paged](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_join_paged) and [posts_orderby](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_orderby) to update the join and order strings.  This will allow you to order by whatever you want as long as you join it first rather than WP_Query assuming that the field has to exist for that particular post. You can then remove the `meta_key`, `orderby`, and `order from your WP_Query args.

Below is an example.  At the top of each function I had to escape out for certain cases since it will add this to everything that uses WP_Query.  You may need to modify that to fit your particular needs.

Documentation on these two filters is sadly lacking so... good luck! :)

```
add_filter('posts_join_paged', 'edit_join', 999, 2);
add_filter('posts_orderby', 'edit_orderby', 999, 2);

/**
 * Edit join
 *
 * @param string $join_paged_statement
 * @param WP_Query $wp_query
 * @return string
 */
function edit_join($join_paged_statement, $wp_query)
{
    global $wpdb;
    if (
        !isset($wp_query->query)
        || $wp_query->is_page
        || $wp_query->is_admin
        || (isset($wp_query->query['post_type']) && $wp_query->query['post_type'] != 'my_custom_post_type')
    ) {
        return $join_paged_statement;
    }

    $join_to_add = "
        LEFT JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta AS my_custom_meta_key
            ON ({$wpdb->prefix}posts.ID = my_custom_meta_key.post_id
                AND my_custom_meta_key.meta_key = 'my_custom_meta_key')
    ";

    // Only add if it's not already in there
    if (strpos($join_paged_statement, $join_to_add) === false) {
        $join_paged_statement = $join_paged_statement . $join_to_add;
    }

    return $join_paged_statement;
}

/** 
 * Edit orderby
 *
 * @param string $orderby_statement
 * @param WP_Query $wp_query
 * @return string
 */
function edit_orderby($orderby_statement, $wp_query)
{
    if (
        !isset($wp_query->query)
        || $wp_query->is_page
        || $wp_query->is_admin
        || (isset($wp_query->query['post_type']) && $wp_query->query['post_type'] != 'my_custom_post_type')
    ) {
        return $orderby_statement;
    }

    $orderby_statement = "my_custom_meta_key.meta_value DESC";

    return $orderby_statement;
}
```

Comment: The code works. But the meta_value is handled as a string. So 6 is rated higher as 50. Any modifications possible to treat them as numbers?

Comment: @Drivingralle `cast(my_custom_meta_key.meta_value as unsigned) DESC` should do the trick...

Comment: Thanks @tfrommen. `$orderby_statement = "cast(my_custom_meta_key.meta_value as unsigned) DESC";` works great.

Answer (score 0):

This solution worked for me:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'orden_portfolio' );
function orden_portfolio( $query ) {

    if( ! is_admin() ) {

        $query->set( 'orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
        $query->set( 'meta_query', [
            'relation' => 'OR',
            [ 
                'key' => 'ce_orden', 
                'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS' ],
            [
                'key' => 'ce_orden',
                'compare' => 'EXISTS',
            ],
        ] );

        return $query;

    }

}
```

However, this solution first shows the records with null meta_value. This other solution shows ASC order and nulls at the end:

```
function custom_join($join) {
    global $wpdb;

    if( ! is_admin() ) {
        $join .= $wpdb->prepare(
        ' LEFT JOIN ' . $wpdb->postmeta . ' cpm ON cpm.post_id = ' . $wpdb->posts . '.ID AND cpm.meta_key = %s'
        , 'ce_orden' );
    }

    return $join;
}

add_filter('posts_join','custom_join');

function custom_orderby($orderby_statement){
    global $wpdb;

    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        $orderby_statement = "CAST( COALESCE(cpm.meta_value,99999) as SIGNED INTEGER) ASC";
    }

    return $orderby_statement;
}

add_filter('posts_orderby','custom_orderby', 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by using one query and proper args. WP 4.1+

```
$args = array( 
    'posts_per_page' => -1, 
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'OR',
        array(
            'key' => 'custom_sort',
            'compare' => 'EXISTS'
        ),
        array(
            'key' => 'custom_sort',
            'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
        )
    ),
    'orderby' => 'meta_value_num title',
    'order' => 'ASC',
));

$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

See my full answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/370841/15209

Answer (score 0):

I ended up tapping into the 'get_meta_sql' filter that Wordpress provides

```
add_filter( 'get_meta_sql', 'adjust_the_meta_sql' ), 10, 2 );
```

The function looks like this

```
function adjust_the_meta_sql( $sql, $queries ) {
            if ( 'my_post_type' === filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'post_type' )
                && '_my_key' === $queries[0]['key'] ) {
                $sql['join']  = preg_replace( '/INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON \(([^)]+)\)/', 'LEFT JOIN wp_postmeta ON ($1 ' . $sql['where'] . ')', $sql['join'] );
                $sql['where'] = '';
            }
            return $sql;
        }
```

It solves two problems with the Wordpress generated sql.

1. Turns the INNER JOIN into a LEFT JOIN
2. Moves the WHERE clause into the ON clause.

Your particular query may be different, so be sure to test and adjust as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Folks, thank you for all the valid answers but, right now (2022), nesting is the key:

```
$query->set( 'orderby', array(
     'meta_value_num' => 'DESC',
     'title' => 'ASC' )
); // order priorities

$query->set( 'meta_query', array(
     'featured' => array(
          'relation' => 'OR',
          array(
               'key' => '_featured',
               'value' => '1', // show first the posts with value = 1
          ),
          array( // these nested rules have less priority for ordering but make us sure to show all other posts 
               'relation' => 'OR',
               array(
                    'key' => '_featured',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS', // explains itself
               ),
               array(
                    'key' => '_featured',
                    'value' => '0', // the case which the value exists but needs to be considered as not
               )
          )
     )
));
```

Bonus case: I didn't test this but if the meta is not a 0/1 value, the third rule should be:

```
array(
      'key' => '_featured',
      'value' => '[priority value]',
      'compare' => '!='
)
```