# Order by optional meta key?

Tags: wp-query, post-meta, order

I'm building the sorting functionality for a custom post type, and I have a custom meta value for "Featured" posts. This value is set when you tick the checkbox, otherwise it is not set.

Using the default `orderby=meta_value` with `meta_key=featured` makes it so that the screen only displays posts that have the meta key. If they don't, they don't even appear.

I want it so if it is not set, they do appear, but they appear last. I assume I need to use `meta_query` instead, but I couldn't get that to work either.

**How do I allow empty, false, or non-existing meta keys in the WP_Query arguments?**

My code is below. This is for sorting columns in the dashboard, so it is modifying the default WP Query args.

```
function featured_sortable_order( $vars ) {
  if ( isset($vars['orderby']) && $vars['orderby'] == 'featured' ) {

    $vars = array_merge( $vars, array(
      'meta_key' => 'featured',
      'orderby' => 'meta_value',
      'order'     => isset($vars['order']) ? $vars['order'] : 'asc',
    ) );

  }
  return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'request', 'featured_sortable_order' );
```

Comment: To clarify you are looking to have a "sticky" (featured) functionality? And you wish the sort to happen based on the meta_key value being present giving preference to the order?

Comment: I ran into this problem not too long ago - looked into maybe combining 2 queries together but in the end I just decided to go with 2 queries / 2 loops. That's the inefficient "get it done" solution though.

Comment: @codearachnid Yes, a _custom_ sticky feature although from the dashboard they are the same. All the sorting would do is either put all featured posts first, or last, but not exclude non-featured posts.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee I just hope I don't have to hack it. I'd like to learn the proper way :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Completely edited after first publish

The problem is that to order for a meta value, WordPress need to `'meta_key'` in query is set to something.
But if you set `'meta_key'` to something, then WordPress will add something like

```
AND ( wp_postmeta.meta_key = 'the_meta_key' )
```

to `WHERE` SQL clause; and something like

```
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta ON ( wp_posts.ID = wp_postmeta.post_id )
```

to `join` clauses. So query returns only the posts that has that meta query.

Once you are working on backend, and you call `get_post_meta( $postid, 'featured', true)` for every post to show the column, is not a great performance issue call it 2 times thanks to WordPress cache on get meta function.

So, the idea is get all the posts (without adding filter on meta key), then filter posts using `'posts_results'` hook and order posts looking at the 'featured' meta key.

I'll remove the filter just after having used it.

```
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'order_by_featured', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );

function order_by_featured ( $posts, $query ) {
  // run only on admin, on main query and only if 'orderby' is featured
  if ( is_admin() && $query->is_main_query() && $query->get('orderby') === 'featured' ) {
    // run once
    remove_filter( current_filter(), __FUNCTION__, PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
    $nonfeatured = array();
    $featured = array();
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
      if ( get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'featured', TRUE ) ) {
        $featured[] = $post;
      } else {
        $nonfeatured[] = $post;
      }
    }
    $order = strtoupper( $query->get('order') ) === 'ASC' ? 'DESC' : 'ASC';
    // if order is ASC put featured at top, otherwise put featured at bottm
    $posts = ( $order === 'ASC' )
      ? array_merge( $nonfeatured, $featured )
      : array_merge( $featured, $nonfeatured );
  }
  return $posts;
}
```

In addition, I add a filter on `'pre_get_post'` to use `'ASC'` as default order if no order is set in the query:

```
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', function( $query ) {
  // if no order is set set order to ASC
  if (
    is_admin() && $query->is_main_query()
    && $query->get('orderby') === 'featured' 
    && $query->get('order') === ''
  ) {
    $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow that's a lot of code to get this to work! It's not quite right though (http://radleygh.com/images/chrome_2014-080-15-55-54-79.png). I'll have to debug this more next week, I'm leaving right now. Thanks though! (It looks like an edit was made while i was testing, it may be fixed, but I can't check yet!)

Comment: @RadGH I've completely edited the answer. Now it works without issues for me, however, once this is actually *another* answer...

Comment: In your opinion, do you think this is faster than running 2 queries separately? In multiple queries you are only getting what you need, then displaying them. In this method you are pulling *all* posts, then looping through each post to check if it's featured. Or do you think there isn't a performance difference?

Comment: Why you should get all posts? I run a query that contain the posts that you get using 2 queries. Instead of running 2 queries and then merging, I run a query that return the already merged items. They will be unordered, off course, so I order them. I perform one query, where your method performs 2, but I do a loop where you doesn't. Which is faster? It depends on a lot of things, number of posts, database server, memory available for scripts... This sort of things got an ansewr only by testing. @Howdy_McGee

Comment: After some testing, `posts_results` only pulls the number of posts via `posts_per_page` parameter, so the above scenario would only work if you actually are displaying all posts on a single page. Is that correct or could I be implementing it wrong?

Comment: @Howdy_McGee yes, this is intened to order a given set of posts based on be featured or not. I.E. you have a query that returns 20 posts and 5 are featured and 15 not. With my code you can have the featured at top (or at bottom) passing 'orderby' => 'featured'. That means if you have some post that are featured, but are not included in the query, you'll not get them.

Comment: Incompatible with pagination, unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

Why not giving all posts the meta attribute with a custom value?

I mean, you can set all posts to featured = no/false/0/low-numeric-valeu and then change to yes/true/1/high-numeric-values all those that should be featured and they will get ordered, won't they?

Comment: That would work and I did consider it. I just expected there to be support for missing meta keys. And this key applies to many post types. And there are already pages. I would have to fill the gaps when the plugin is activated, which I guess isn't a terrible idea since it is a custom meta key after all. It does feel a bit unecessary though.