# posts_results filter - additional sort, with a meta value, to move posts to the end of the results, with pagination working

Tags: filters, pagination, array, sort

I have a custom post type for business locations that I am trying to add an additional sorting filter to by using a custom meta value. The custom field specifies whether or not the location is open or closed. The default sorting is being done alphabetically by post title, but I would like to add this additional sort so that any location with the value "Closed" will be moved to the very end of the query results.

**Edit**: Some additional context based on a comment: currently there are only 2 location statuses; "Open" and "Closed," but there is a possibility of there being another added in the future (ie "Temporarily Closed"). In that scenario those posts would remain in alphabetical order, I really only want the ones that are "Closed" to be at the end of the results.

I found [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/138794/13286) which has gotten me most of the way there, the only problem I am facing now is that the query only shows 9 posts per page, and while the "Closed" post does get moved to the bottom of the results on initial load, it's only on a per-page basis currently. For instance, I have a "Closed" location that, alphabetically, is #3 in the results, and with this filter enabled it is getting moved to the 9th position, but the query itself has 30 results overall, so when I start loading more posts, "Open" locations end up loading in after this initial "Closed" one. Is there an easy way to make this filter work while keeping the pagination intact? I would prefer not to query all the posts at once and fake the pagination with JavaScript/CSS.

```
function order_by_closed($posts, $query) {
    $postType = $query->get('post_type');

    if ($postType == 'location') {
        $open = array();
        $closed = array();

        // Separate posts by open/closed
        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            if (get_field('location_status', $post->ID) == 'Closed') {
                $closed[] = $post;
            } else {
                $open[] = $post;
            }
        }

        // Merge arrays with closed locations at the end
        $posts = array_merge($open, $closed);
    }

    return $posts;
}
add_filter( 'posts_results', 'order_by_closed', PHP_INT_MAX, 2 );
```

Comment: The question you've linked to talks about adding an order by to the SQL query (which I think is the way to do this). Have you done that, or have you just copied the post_results filter part of the answer?

Comment: @Rup Thank you, yes, I did try adding that but it didn't seem to have any affect. I think that was in regard to something else. Other commenters said that the solution does not support pagination.

Comment: If the meta_key=location_status has only two values for all posts in cpt: Open or Close, why don't you order by meta_value with desc order in the WP_Query arguments?

Comment: @birgire because I need the posts to be in alphabetical order by title and only the "Closed" locations should be at the very bottom. There's also a possibility that an additional location status will be added in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so why doesn't this work:

The Filter you are using is the `posts_results`, which is a filter that is applied *AFTER* the Results are retrieved from the database. Which has the problem that you are describing: Ordering happens on a page-per-page basis.

What you want to do is add an order TO the SQL-Query, so that the order is applied to the complete result and your Locations are retrieved first open, then closed.

The way to do that is to remove the `posts_results` filter, and then use the `pre_get_posts` action:

```php
function wpse_420312_order_locations_by_open_closed( $query ) {
    //First we need to check that this is the "main" query and that we're not on a backend page
    if ( $query->is_main_query() && !is_admin() ) {
        $post_type = $query->get('post_type');
        if ( $post_type === 'location' ) {
            //we need to build a meta query. To learn more, look here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/
            $meta_query = array(
                //to sort by a meta query, we have to name it
                'location_status' => array(
                    //luckily, ACF saved custom fields with their name as the meta_key
                    'key' => 'location_status',
                    //we only want to see locations that have the status information
                    'compare' => 'EXISTS'
                )
            );
            $query->set( 'meta_query', $meta_query );
            //sort by: location Status DESC (first "Open", then "Closed"), then post title ASC
            $query->set( 'orderby', array( 'location_status' => 'DESC', 'title' => 'ASC', 'ID' => 'ASC' ) );
        }
    }
}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_420312_order_locations_by_open_closed' );
```

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This is definitely doing something, but it doesn't seem to give the intended result. The posts are no longer returning in order of post title on page load and I am still seeing the "closed" location in the initial 9 results. I can't really figure out what order they're being returned in on load, but the first post in the list starts with a "T" now and when I click "Load More" I am getting the 2nd page of results in alphabetical order, but I am getting duplicate posts since the initial 9 posts are not in alphabetical order.

Comment: @HU is Sebastian: Shouldn't `$query->set( 'order', ... )` instead be `$query->set( 'orderby', ... )`? See the *'orderby' with multiple 'meta_key's* example in the WordPress documentation for [WP_Query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters).

Comment: @kofeigen that seemed to have helped. The posts are now returning in alphabetical order again on load and my "Closed" location is no longer showing up in the initial 9 results. The only remaining issue is that I am still getting duplicate posts when I load more (the last 3 posts in the initial results are also the first 3 posts when I load more). The "Closed" location is never returned, I'm assuming because the 3 duplicate posts are throwing off the count. Do I maybe have to make adjustments to my load more posts function as well?

Comment: @user13286 Could you please post the code for your load more posts function?

Comment: @user13286 A completely different approach might be needed though. Is the list of posts displayed by a default theme template (e.g. archive.html) or your own custom-made template? Why do you need a *load more posts* function? Why can't default pagination (functions) be used? Will you ever require translation? Could you ever want to accommodate additional location status options that could influence sorting? Right now, sort order is based on "chance". There are only two English-language status labels. If 3 labels ever required a specific sequence the current suggested solutions might not work.

Comment: @kofeigen Damn, you're right. I fixed the "orderby" typo and added the sorting by ID to prevent duplicates when using "normal" pagination in case there are locations with the same title.

Comment: @kofeigen Load more function is [essentially this](https://gist.github.com/matheuscl/9349d3eab71e041d071e8747d82513d0) with some light modifications. The theme is custom-built using the old PHP function/template method. I am using load more because I prefer it to the standard pagination. I don't think that should make a difference though as the underlying logic/functionality, as it pertains to getting additional pages of results, is essentially the same as standard pagination, no? This will not require translation but there likely will be an additional "temporarily closed" status in the future

Comment: @user13286 A debugging effort is needed to resolve the remaining problems. What functions and/or data have you validated so far? Are the POST parameters correct in the request? Is the load more function receiving the desired parameter values? Is this function using the desired values in the call to WP\_Query? Does WP\_Query produce identical results using those values within the function and outside the function (e.g. in a shortcode used for testing)? Is the code that processes the AJAX response receiving the desired data? It's hard to evaluate any of this without seeing the *actual* code.

Comment: @user13286 Just FYI, the proposed solution will not work once *Temporarily Closed* is added as a **location_status**. A descending alphabetic order will place *Temporarily Closed* posts at the start of the list. My answer to your question: *Is there an easy way to make this filter work while keeping the pagination intact?* is "No." There is a viable solution. But, it involves quite a few changes. If you are willing to show your code to help with resolving the duplicate posts problem, I can try to outline a solution to fit with your pagination.