# Order posts by meta_value even if meta_key is not filled

Tags: order, sort

I want to sort search results by the value of custom field ('name-official') for all posts (is this field filled or not).
But when I add filter in **function.php** like

```
function searchExcludePages($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('orderby','meta_value');
        $query->set('meta_key','name-official');
        $query->set('order','ASC');
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','searchExcludePages');
```

i've received results with filled 'name-official' only. What should i do to get results with non-filled field too?

---

```
$query->set(
            'meta_query',
            array(
                'relation' => 'OR', # Matches to this meta_query should be added to those matching the 'meta_key' query
                array(
                    'key' => 'name-official',
                    'value' => 'non-exist-value',
                    'compare' => 'NOT EXISTS'
                )
            )
        );

        $query->set('orderby','meta_value date');
        $query->set('meta_key','name-official');       
        $query->set('order','DESC');
```

Comment: I remember having a similar problem. I solved it by adding an empty meta_data value to all posts which didn't have the meta_data... I'll do some research to see if there is a better option as I find this quite interesting.

Comment: Oh right, you have this entire thread which discussed this issue: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/102447/sort-on-meta-value-but-include-posts-that-dont-have-one

Comment: Thanks for reply! 

Yes, i can add this meta_data everywhere but it is not good solution.
About link - i've tried it, but with such code i don't see any results.

Comment: Do you have the updated code that tried the linked solution?  It looks to me like it should work, perhaps with a little debugging for specific cases.

Comment: Yes, i've added snippet to question. It would be great if you can give some advice.