# How do I see the mysql query generated by get_posts( $args )?

Tags: query, mysql, get-posts, sql

I'm trying to use get_posts( $args ) to get some custom post types. Is there a way to see the mysql query generated by the get_posts function?

Comment: This isn't an answer, more a recommendation, but check out the query monitor plugin. Also, use `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts`

Comment: This might help you - https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/4809/how-to-display-sql-query-that-ran-in-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to Tom J Nowell for pointing me to using `WP_Query` instead of `get_posts`. With WP_Query you have the entire `WP_Query` object to reference. So something like the following gives the actual mysql query of the args I was using.

```
// these same args also worked with get_posts()
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
);

// create a new WP_Query object with the args above
$the_object = new WP_Query($args);

// show the mysql as a string
echo $the_object->request;

// see EVERYTHING in the WP_Query object
var_dump($the_object);
```