# Add custom post types stats to a custom dashboard widget

Tags: custom-post-types, widgets, dashboard

I have a lot of custom post types and I have them showing in my "Right Now" Dashboard but it's gotten pretty long so I want to separate them to a custom widget within the dash.

See example below:

[image]

So my question is how do I add the CPTs to a custom dashboard widget?

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is what I have (What am I missing?)

```
// wp_dashboard_setup is the action hook

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'mycustom_moviestats');


// add dashboard widget
function mycustom_moviestats() {

wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_movie_widget', 'Movie Stats',                  'custom_dashboard_movie_list');

}

function custom_dashboard_movie_list(){

// here is the code to add custom post types + count see below

function my_right_now() {
$num_widgets = wp_count_posts( 'widget' );

$num = number_format_i18n( $num_widgets->publish );
$text = _n( 'Widget', 'Widgets', $num_widgets->publish );
if ( current_user_can( 'edit_pages' ) ) { 
    $num = "<a href='edit.php?post_type=widget'>$num</a>";
    $text = "<a href='edit.php?post_type=widget'>$text</a>";
}   

echo '<tr>';
echo '<td class="first b b_pages">' . $num . '</td>';
echo '<td class="t pages">' . $text . '</td>';
echo '</tr>';
}
add_action( 'right_now_content_table_end', 'my_right_now' );

}
```

Comment: dashboard "meta box" is called a dashboard widget

Comment: I've added an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lokks like you have a function declared inside another function, your code is wrong, try this:

```
// wp_dashboard_setup is the action hook
add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'mycustom_moviestats');

// add dashboard widget
function mycustom_moviestats() {
    wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_movie_widget', 'Movie Stats','custom_dashboard_movie_list');
}

function custom_dashboard_movie_list(){

    $args = array(
        'public' => true ,
        '_builtin' => false );
    $output = 'object';
    $operator = 'and';
    echo '<table>';
    //loop over all custom post types
    $post_types = get_post_types( $args , $output , $operator );
    foreach( $post_types as $post_type ) {
        $num_posts = wp_count_posts( $post_type->name );
        $num = number_format_i18n( $num_posts->publish );
        $text = _n( $post_type->labels->singular_name, $post_type->labels->name , intval( $num_posts->publish ) );
        if ( current_user_can( 'edit_posts' ) ) {
            $num = "<a href='edit.php?post_type=$post_type->name'>$num</a>";
            $text = "<a href='edit.php?post_type=$post_type->name'>$text</a>";
        }
        echo '<tr><td class="first b b-' . $post_type->name . '">' . $num . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="t ' . $post_type->name . '">' . $text . '</td></tr>';
    }

    //loop over all taxonomies
    $taxonomies = get_taxonomies( $args , $output , $operator ); 
    foreach( $taxonomies as $taxonomy ) {
        $num_terms  = wp_count_terms( $taxonomy->name );
        $num = number_format_i18n( $num_terms );
        $text = _n( $taxonomy->labels->singular_name, $taxonomy->labels->name , intval( $num_terms ));
        if ( current_user_can( 'manage_categories' ) ) {
            $num = "<a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=$taxonomy->name'>$num</a>";
            $text = "<a href='edit-tags.php?taxonomy=$taxonomy->name'>$text</a>";
        }
        echo '<tr><td class="first b b-' . $taxonomy->name . '">' . $num . '</td>';
        echo '<td class="t ' . $taxonomy->name . '">' . $text . '</td></tr>';
    }
    echo '</table>';
}
```

Comment: that did the trick. Now styling it would be even better. : ) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work.

```
// wp_dashboard_setup is the action hook

add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'mycustom_moviestats');


// add dashboard widget
function mycustom_moviestats() {


wp_add_dashboard_widget('custom_movie_widget', 'widget name', 'custom_dashboard_movie_list');

}

function custom_dashboard_movie_list(){

// here is the code to add custom post types + count see below

}
```

The code to add custom post types + count has already been answered and it would clutter this. It can be found here,

[Adding Custom Post Type Counts to the Dashboard](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5318/adding-custom-post-type-counts-to-the-dashboard)
[Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file)

Comment: whats `global $wp_meta_boxes;` for?

Comment: @Wyck I tried that combo and it didn't work for me.

Comment: @Bainternet got it: dashboard widget.

Comment: just tried it and it works fine you just need to echo out the stats from within `custom_dashboard_movie_list` function

Comment: woops ya I will remove global

Comment: @Bainternet I edited my original post to reflect the code I have. Not sure what I'm missing. Thanks!