# Display text if current user has written 1 or more posts in a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types

I am trying to display different things to new users that have not created a post versus users who have created a post.

I tried this, but it did not work for custom post types (only normal posts) and it does not account for drafts or pending posts:

```
<?php if (count_user_posts(1)>=1) { blah blah blah } else {Welcome, blah blah blah }; ?>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hi **@Carson:**

A simple function to address what you are asking for might be the function `yoursite_user_has_posts()` which leverages the built in `WP_Query` class:

```
function yoursite_user_has_posts($user_id) {
  $result = new WP_Query(array(
    'author'=>$user_id,
    'post_type'=>'any',
    'post_status'=>'publish',
    'posts_per_page'=>1,
  ));
  return (count($result->posts)!=0);
}
```

You can then call it from your theme like this:

```
<?php
$user = wp_get_current_user();
if ($user->ID)
  if (yoursite_user_has_posts($user->ID))
    echo 'Thank you for writing!';
  else
    echo 'Get Writing!';
?>
```

Comment: that won't work as `count($result->posts)` will return 10 or something like that. you need to either replace that with `$result->found_posts` or add the `posts_per_page => -1` argument. not to mention the huge resource drag. if the user has 1000+ posts you'll probably get your account suspended for this on a shared host :)

Comment: @Ambitious Amoeba - Not sure why you say it won't work. The OP wanted to know if zero or if not zero and 10 is not zero. Fair point about the resource, except it's using the default which means only 10 posts anyway, not 1000+. Yes, there are 20 different ways to do this, but it achieves the OP's goal. There are definitely other more performant ways to achieve it but they require more code and I was trying to keep it simple because, based on the OP's question it seems that simpler would be better for him.

Comment: Remember the user only wants to know if a user has created 1 or more posts, we don't need to select all of them to figure out if the user has at least 1 post.. (something i think you overlooked when commenting).. though @Mike i'd sugget updating the code sample to check a particular post type, else that code will match all sorts(when the user did specificy a particular type).

Comment: .. further... you don't even need to return a count, if the query is empty then we know the query got 0 results(ie. the user has no posts), so you could do a return value based on whether the result was empty(true/false). If the query was not empty we can therefore postulate that there are posts associated with the user(Mike you following what i'm getting at?)..

Comment: @t31os - Yes, I hear ya. I guess I was getting lazy on answer 193... :)  Is that any better? Yes I could do direct SQL and make it tighter but I prefer not to use direct SQL in WordPress if possible.

Comment: I wasn't suggesting direct SQL...My first comment was primarily directed at Ambitious Amoeba, highlighting that *we don't need all a user's posts to figure out if we have 1*... the follow up comment was merely a suggestion regarding the return result.. (sorry i should make better use of the @, my fault for not making the comments clear).. ;)

Comment: Thank you guys MikeSchinkel and the others!!  I am going to take a run at this tonight and I will let you know how it goes.

Comment: Mike, Thank you!  This works with the exception that the function call echos are flip-flopped (at least for me they were).  Once I made that change, the correct message was given to users who have/have not started a post.  Thanks again.

Comment: @Carson - Doh! Yes, I did flip them, fixed now. Hey also, if you got an answer to your question could you go ahead and select a best answer for this question? You'd click the checkmark next to the answer you think is best. Those ratings are what we get for helping, so when you ask a question and get a good answer always remember to reward the person who helps. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

see [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4167#4167):

```
function atom_count($user_id, $what_to_count = 'post') {
  global $wpdb;    
  $where = $what_to_count == 'comment' ? "WHERE comment_approved = 1 AND user_id = {$user_id}" : get_posts_by_author_sql($what_to_count, TRUE, $user_id);
  $from = "FROM ".(($what_to_count == 'comment') ? $wpdb->comments : $wpdb->posts);    
  $count = $wpdb->get_var($wpdb->prepare("SELECT COUNT(*) {$from} {$where}"));
  return $count;
}
```

if you want this to count all posts, regardless of the type, and status, change `get_posts_by_author_sql()` with `"WHERE post_author = '{$user_id}'"`

didn't test that, but it should work...

Comment: This will break with the next DB change. Use the API whenever possible, not some custom SQL.

Comment: I'll add "Use the API whenever possible and there's isn't a more efficient method". DB doesn't change every day, I doubt that any of the fields in the function above ever will.

Comment: Amoeba - Efficiency can be overrated. I'd rather spend a few milliseconds than to learn that code I wrote last year broke and the client wants it fixed *now!* :)

Answer (score 1):

This should do what you want...

```
<?php if ( 0 == count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTOMPOSTTYPE" ) && is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>
   Do something if they have no posts
<?php } elseif ( 0 !== count_user_posts( get_current_user_id(), "CUSTOMPOSTTYPE" ) && is_user_logged_in() ) { ?>    
   Do something else if they do have a post         
<?php } ?>
```