# How can I customize "Pages" admin (edit.php) and "Edit Page" admin (post.php) for bulk edit of custom content type?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, customization

I think its probably easier than I think to do this, but currently its beyond me. If there are any plugins out there I'd prefer to start there rather than develop from scratch, but I'll do what I have to do.

I have already created a custom content type called "biblio" that I will use to hold and display Bibliography info. Each entry will contain:

**Title**: Will re-use page title field
**Abstract**:  Will re-use content field
**Tags**: Will re-use Tags field
**Authors**: Custom field (with ability to add multiple)
**Date**: Custom field
**Publication**: Custom field
**Doc ID**: Custom field
**Link to external article**: Custom field
**Keywords**:  Custom field (with ability to add multiple)

**What I need**

1. A way to customize the edit post
   page for my custom content type to
   show only specified default and
   custom fields (may not be needed if I can get #2 below)
2. A way to be able to
   bulk edit these in a user friendly
   way (not using my PHPMyAdmin).

I have tried a number of plugins. One really useful one is Custom Content Type Manager (thanks fireproofsocks, whoever you are). But I still need to be able to do the 2 things I mentioned above.

By way of example there is a great set of plugins next gen gallery plus custom fields for next gen gallery that works how I would like the admin side of my custom content type.

Any info leading to a way to do #1 #2 above would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

## Do not edit core files.

.

### 1.

Assuming you have a registered a custom post type called biblio, you can add and remove "stuff" within your functions.php.

For instance this removes some meta boxes from 'biblio'

```
function remove_default_page_screen_metaboxes() {
 global $post_type;

 remove_meta_box( 'commentstatusdiv','biblio','normal' ); // Comments Metabox
 remove_meta_box('commentsdiv','biblio','normal'); // Comments
 remove_meta_box( 'trackbacksdiv','biblio','normal' ); // Talkback Metabox
 remove_meta_box( 'authordiv','biblio','normal' ); // Author Metabox
}
add_action('admin_menu','remove_default_page_screen_metaboxes');
```

you can remove and add meta boxes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_meta_box

Reference of all default meta boxes [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/1569#1569)

Read this http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/04/29/custom-post-types-in-wordpress

and this http://wptheming.com/2010/08/custom-metabox-for-post-type/

### 2.

By 'bulk edit' what exactly do you want to bulk edit? You screenshot shows what is called custom columns, you can add or remove these using the Wordpress API
http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column

An example
http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/add-admin-columns-in-wordpress

Comment: **+1** on the **"Do not edit core files!"**

Comment: Thanks so much! I consider #1 to be answered!  With regard to #2 thanks for the links. And that plugin looks useful if I want to display read-only data. What I'd like is for there to be open fields there instead of read only data. I'm not a super strong coder so not sure how to do that. Thanks!