# Add content to wordpress edit.php page

Tags: custom-post-types, filters

I want to add some content, in the top or bottom of the wordpress edit.php page for a custom post type. What is the right filter or way to do this ?

Comment: What kind of content?

Comment: Some tags, html content

Answer (score 1):

The action `load-edit.php` is not needed. The answer on Stack Overflow is based on this WPSE answer: [How do you create a custom edit.php / edit pages page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/115164/12615) that uses `pre_get_posts`, that's why it was encapsulated inside `load-PAGE` action.

On the screen `edit.php` we don't have any action hooks to insert content. We can only use the filter `views_edit-POST_TYPE` to do something there. With jQuery we can adjust the position on screen.

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-POST_TYPE', function($views){
    echo '<h2 style="display:none;" id="my-element">My Custom HTML</h2>';
    echo "<script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            $('#my-element').detach().insertBefore('#ajax-response').fadeIn();
        });
        </script>";
    return $views;
});
```

Without jQuery it prints on position 1, and on position 2 using it.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Try following these lines to add html content to **edit.php**:

```
<?php
# Called only in /wp-admin/edit.php pages
add_action( 'load-edit.php', function() {
  add_filter( 'views_edit-talk', 'talk_tabs' ); // talk is my custom post type
});

# echo the tabs
function talk_tabs() {
 echo '
  <h2 class="nav-tab-wrapper">
    <a class="nav-tab" href="admin.php?page=guests">Profiles</a>
    <a class="nav-tab nav-tab-active" href="edit.php?post_type=talk">Talks</a>
    <a class="nav-tab" href="edit.php?post_type=offer">Offers</a>
  </h2>
 ';
}
?>
```

*Source: [Stack Overflow - Add content to edit.php](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895321)*

Comment: But I dont wanna create new tabs

Comment: Why don't you just put a link as comment to the [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32895321) you have copied paste it from, you not even giving credits to that user on stackoverflow!

Comment: I am not just putting a link as a comment, as most of the users prefer the exact part of the solution in the answer. I have seen numerous times users are requesting the others to do that. However, I will include the link to the original answer from now.