# How to control manual excerpt length?

Tags: excerpt

I have a website in which I need to control the displayed excerpt length.
Some of the posts might have manual excerpt so I can't use the `excerpt_length` filter.

I can, of course, use some kind of `substr()`, but was looking for a more elegant solution (if such exists).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look on my answer here: [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/6225#6225)

If I understood your question correctly, it does what you are looking for.

Place this in `functions.php`:

```
function excerpt($num) {
    $limit = $num+1;
    $excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
    array_pop($excerpt);
    $excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt)."... (<a href='" .get_permalink($post->ID) ." '>Read more</a>)";
    echo $excerpt;
}
```

Then, in your theme, use the code `<?php excerpt('22'); ?>` to limit the excerpt to 22 characters.

:)

Comment: Your function should use a proper integer and not a string to pass numeric values or could just convert inside the function, eg. `$num = (int) $num;`. `'1' != 1` .. :)

Comment: Is this still the best practice? Or is there a more efficient approach now?

Answer (score 6):

With the **recent version** of *Wordpress* (v.3.3.0+), you can actually use [`wp_trim_words`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_trim_words).

```
function excerpt($limit) {
    return wp_trim_words(get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
}
```

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17177847/851045

Answer (score 1):

I'd say just look at how core does it: http://phpxref.ftwr.co.uk/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php.source.html#l1840

I took the liberty of putting the code here for ease of copying and pasting.

```
global $post;
if( empty($post->post_excerpt) ){
  $text = apply_filters( 'the_excerpt', get_the_excerpt() );
} else {
  $text = $post->post_excerpt;
  $text = strip_shortcodes( $text );
  $text = apply_filters('the_content', $text);
  $text = str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', $text);
  $text = strip_tags($text);
  $excerpt_length = apply_filters('excerpt_length', 55);
  $excerpt_more = apply_filters('excerpt_more', ' ' . '[...]');
  $words = preg_split("/[\n\r\t ]+/", $text, $excerpt_length + 1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
  if ( count($words) > $excerpt_length ) {
    array_pop($words);
    $text = implode(' ', $words);
    $text = $text . $excerpt_more;
  } else {
    $text = implode(' ', $words);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply it can be done as below .

```
function custom_excerpt_length( $length ) {
    return 20;
}
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'custom_excerpt_length', 999 );
```

Reference: [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/excerpt_length)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:  You can control the amount of words the excert outputs with the filter "excerpt_length"  below are a couple examples of how you can control the size based on different conditions

```
add_filter( 'excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length' );
function new_excerpt_length( $more ) {
    if(is_front_page()){
        if(has_post_thumbnail()){
            return 15;
        } else {
            return 45;
        }
    } else {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Crap, I just noticed that you said the filter approach was a no go.  oh well this is for other people who get here via google and want this then.

Answer (score -1):

Enter this code in your `functions.php`

```
/* easy excerpt limitation
*/
function
easy_excerpt($limit) {
$excerpt = explode(' ', get_the_excerpt(), $limit);
if (count($excerpt)>=$limit) {
array_pop($excerpt);
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
} else {
$excerpt = implode(" ",$excerpt);
}
$excerpt = preg_replace('`[[^]]*]`','',$excerpt);
return $excerpt;
}
```

and use  `echo easy excerpt(mylimit)`  instead of `the_excerpt()`
It works fine.

Comment: Please post a real solution

Comment: You should properly indent your code for readability, check the [formatting help section](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/editing-help#comment-formatting) ;-)