# Displaying latest Posts - fixed height - Excerpt vs. Content?

Tags: content, excerpt

On my static frontpage, I would like to fetch the two latest posts as shown in this [link](http://www.dobschin.com/wp-layout.png).

Now the posts should always be displayed like this (i.e. constant height, limited number of characters), no matter what! If the post uses the more-tag or not - it should always look like in the picture.

How can that be achieved?

I tried both content and excerpt but somehow there always are cases in which the layout gets messed up. Is there a 'standard' way of doing this?

(I'm just asking about getting the actual content, i.e. the "text text text" bit - I have done all the rest)

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

The simple way to do this is to define the height/width in CSS of a container, and then apply a trim on the excerpt.

To change default excerpt length add this to you functions.php

```
function new_excerpt_length($length) { 
    return 100; // change this to how many any characters you want
}

add_filter('excerpt_length', 'new_excerpt_length');
```

Manually controlling the excerpt
[How to control manual excerpt length?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6310/howto-control-manual-excerpt-length)

Outside th loop
[Using wp_trim_excerpt to get the_excerpt() outside the loop](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/using-wp-trim-excerpt-to-get-the-excerpt-outside-the-loop)

The same filters can be applied to the content, but the excerpt suits this better.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because the excerpt limits words and not characters you will always get different heights. You can limit the excerpt to number of characters to make it more accurate:

```
function excerpt($num) {
    echo utf8_encode(substr(get_the_excerpt(), 0, $num+1)) . "...";
}
```

and then call it with:

```
excerpt('55')
```

this way you'll get the first 55 characters followed by ...
overflow:hidded; may also help.