# How to implement pagination eg. newer - 3 - 4 - 5 - 6 - 7 - older

Tags: pagination

How can I implement pagination like shown in the title perhaps something similar to most sites

[image]

Comment: Might be of use (incl. comment in there): [Enable Numeric Pagination](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/1601#1601)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can across this awesome tutorial just the other day:

http://design.sparklette.net/teaches/how-to-add-wordpress-pagination-without-a-plugin/

which is a modified version of this one:

http://www.kriesi.at/archives/how-to-build-a-wordpress-post-pagination-without-plugin

Answer (score 3):

You can use WP-PageNavi
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-pagenavi/

Comment: Beat me by seconds. :) +1 great plugin, functional and customizable.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. Here are 2 solutions, were the first needs some coding from your side and the second is "hit and run" plus is semantically correct: A list.

1. [`paginate_link()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links) function
2. my ["easy pagination deamon"](https://github.com/franz-josef-kaiser/Easy-Pagination-Deamon) plugin
   -> offers a template tag (you can change the name) like `oxo_pagination( $range);` that outputs the following:
   `[first][previous][1][2][3][4][5][next][last]`
   With the $range attribute you can tell how many page links you want to have (seen from current one) and you also got a small stylesheet that gives you the ability to target every part of the pagination plus the current one.