# Is wordpress big enough for my project

Tags: themes, plugin-recommendation, theme-recommendation

I have a site some having job postings running using jobber base. Now I am going to shift it in WP using jobroller theme that is of 99 USD. I am a developer who always like MVC rather than these CMS. I was thinking of doing it in Yii. But now I came to know about job roller. So I have 2 questions.

Is jobroller worth 99 USD and will it work for my product? Can WP handle this if I want to do changes every week. As I told earlier, I am also a developer. So I will be doing changes in it but I doubt that I will not be able to do this in such friendly way as it can be easily done in an MVC framework. I am always in favor of OOP and MVC. But I actually don't have much time to develop my own.

So guys please advise me that should I spend some more time and do it in MVC once or I should once continue with WP? Can any one tell me about big sites that are developed in WP?

Comment: Any progress over here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***About OOP Themes)*** There are dozens of Theme- & Plugin-"Frameworks" out there. And some are OOP.

***About custom coding)*** You could also try libraries like [WP Alchemy](http://www.farinspace.com/wpalchemy-metabox/) for meta boxes and custom content. "Rilwis" offers another one. Then you could use some [front end code](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11395/upload-post-thumbnail-from-the-front-end) to insert stuff into Custom Post types.

***About "Jobroller")*** You should post/ask your Q about "Jobroller" in detail at their page. Furthermore is it hard to know if it's a) commercial and b) you didn't explain your needs in detail.

***About WP & Performance)*** Take a look at [this Q](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10463/refactoring-wordpress-to-improve-memory-performance) for a more in depth look.