# cross-host benchmarking with wordpress

Tags: performance, hosting

I am doing some cross-host benchmarking with wordpress, and rather than going to the huge trouble of setting up an identical install of wordpress on each host, a huge investment of time, etc., I want to create a single php file that would simulate the php demands of wordpress and use that file to gauge each host's relative wordpress efficiency.

What might such a file look like? Or does it matter? Would a standard php benchmark file suffice?

Note: for my purposes, I'm ignoring database calls from my calculations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik there's no real performance test available (what exactly do you want to check?), but you can [find a plugin that came out of the first Q below](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612), that might help you doing some profilling.

---

An interesting read might be…

1. [refactoring WP to improve memory performance](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/10463/refactoring-wordpress-to-improve-memory-performance)
2. generally a lot of Qs inside the [performance](/questions/tagged/performance) tag

---

Also: You can use the [Debug Bar Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/debug-bar/):

[image]
<sub>(source: [wordpress.org](http://plugins.svn.wordpress.org/debug-bar/assets/banner-772x250.png))</sub>

---

…or if it's about plugin performance, try to take a look via the [P3 Plugin Performance Profiler Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/). No need to run this on multiple sites, as it meassures in %-values.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at that other post, and the other stuff will certainly help. I have a client with a seemingly terrible host,  On the Firebug net panel, >90% of the render time is in the top line as "waiting", which as I understand is the server's processing the page.  I have several hosting accounts available to move this site to and, all things being equal, I want to see which one would run wordpress the fastest.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to tests different hosts I would suggest running the WordPress unit tests and adding a timer for each test.  You can install the tests via svn which also installs WordPress.  You you just need to create a blank database and change wp-config.php.

Comment: This requires an existing Wordpress installation doesn't it? I'm looking for a light and fast solution (one file if possible), but I'll definitely look into this.

Comment: No when you checkout the tests via svn it downloads all the files including WordPress. See [Automated Testing - Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Automated_Testing)