# How to remove row-actions from pages table?

Tags: functions, admin, customization

I've already found out [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file) how to remove the row-actions from the posts table in wordpress admin. Now I'd like to do the same in the pages table. I've looked in the core files but, well, I just don't get it. Anyone?

Here's the code used in functions.php to remove row actions in posts:

```
function remove_row_actions( $actions )
{
    if( get_post_type() === 'post' )
        unset( $actions['edit'] );
        unset( $actions['view'] );
        unset( $actions['trash'] );
        unset( $actions['inline hide-if-no-js'] );
    return $actions;
}
add_filter( 'post_row_actions', 'remove_row_actions', 10, 1 );
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For non-hierarchical post types the filter is called `post_row_actions`, for [hierarchical it's `page_row_actions`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.1.2/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L560).

If you want to remove all actions you don't have to unset the individual items, you can just return an empty array.

```
add_filter( 'page_row_actions', 'wpse16327_page_row_actions', 10, 2 );
function wpse16327_page_row_actions( $actions, $post )
{
    if ( 'page' == $post->post_type ) {
        return array();
    }
    return $actions;
}
```

Comment: Just an FYI, for any users who found sources that claim these hooks are deprecated (i.e. [Adam Brown's hook reference](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/page_row_actions) - if Adam Brown has since fixed this, please comment) ... know that they are [NOT deprecated](http://goo.gl/DXPaq).  (This misleading information was borne because the regex used for parsing the WP core code was no longer able to pick up these hooks since they were moved inside a ternary operator in [WP 3.1](http://goo.gl/JhurK).)

Comment: Adam Brown's reference was just fixed.  http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/page_row_actions