# Best collection of code for your .htaccess file

Tags: htaccess, customization, code

We have the [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file) thread, so I thought that it might be useful to create a thread for our .htaccess files.

**AND PLEASE REMEMBER TO ADD ANY OF YOUR OWN SNIPPETS TO THIS LIST**

Comment: Great idea.  Of course, the mods should make this a community wiki.  It would also help (well, it would help me) if when answers are posted, a clear explanation of what the change is and how it works.

Comment: Made CW. Also please move your first snippet to answer.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

These are 3 snippet for better performance, regarding Yahoo! rules:

**Disable Etags:**

```
Header unset ETag
FileETag None
```

**Add expire headers:**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ico|jpg|jpeg|png|gif|js|css|swf)$">
Header set Expires "Tue, 16 Jun 2020 20:00:00 GMT"
</FilesMatch>
```

Or

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 1 day"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 10 years"
ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 10 years"
```

**Compress plain text file:**

```
<FilesMatch "\.(js|css|html|htm|php|xml)$">
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
</FilesMatch>
```

Read more about them [here](http://www.deluxeblogtips.com/2010/06/htaccess-rules-website-performace.html).

**Updated:**

**Redirect requests to www domain**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.tld [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.tld/$1 [R=301,L]
```

**Block request to xmlrpc.php**

Use this only when you don't use remote publishing as it can prevent your blog from hacks.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)xmlrpc\.php$ http://www.domain.tld [R=301,L]
```

**Redirect all feeds to feedburner**

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^.*(FeedBurner|FeedValidator) [NC]
RewriteRule ^feed/?.*$ http://feeds.feedburner.com/feed_uri [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: I still believe Yahoo’s recommendation has its source in Yahoobot’s disability to use HTTP 1.1. Validating Entity tags is something different than validating against Last-Modified.

Comment: Don't remove ETags just on a whim, they can be beneficial, it depends on many factors.

Comment: @toscho & @Wyck: Can you explain about Etag? I see all guides about web performance recommend this. What's the problem with it?

Comment: @rilwis ETag is for [strong validation](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3): A changed widget for example doesn’t change Last-Modified but it changes ETag. See also the [Caching Tutorial](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/#VALIDATE).

Comment: @toscho: nice point about ETag vs Last-Modified. Thanks :)

Comment: In IE 9 [download resumption](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2011/06/03/send-an-etag-to-enable-http-206-file-download-resume-without-restarting.aspx) **requires** an ETag.

Answer (score 13):

### Better rewrite rules for WordPress permalinks

By default WordPress sends a 404 HTML page for missing images and stylesheets – they are never rendered by a browser. And it catches your symbolic links.

```
# Images, Stylesheets etc. don't need a HTML 404
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.+\.\w{2,4}$
# Existing file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# Existing directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# Symbolic link
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: I'm curious how this would work for for a multisite configuration?

Comment: @DanGayle There is no difference. The code to redirect everything internally to `index.php` is the same.

Comment: This works great!

Answer (score 8):

Some basic Security stuff.

```bash
# limit indexing of directories
Options All -Indexes

# protect the htaccess file,
# this is done by default with apache config file,
# but you never know.
<files .htaccess>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# disable the server signature
ServerSignature Off

# limit file uploads to 10mb
LimitRequestBody 10240000

# protect wpconfig.php.
<files wp-config.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>

# Limit logins and admin by IP
# this goes in the /admin folder NOT root folder .htaccess
<Limit GET POST PUT>
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xx.xx.xx.xx  //( your static IP)
</Limit>    

# block bad query strings (hackers/bots), please be aware this might break some plugins
# QUERY STRING EXPLOITS
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} \.\.\/    [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} boot\.ini [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} tag\=     [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ftp\:     [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} http\:    [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} https\:   [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mosConfig [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\[|\]|\(|\)|<|>|'|"|;|\?|\*).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%22|%27|%3C|%3E|%5C|%7B|%7C).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(%0|%A|%B|%C|%D|%E|%F|127\.0).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(globals|encode|config|localhost|loopback).* [NC,OR]
 RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(request|select|insert|union|declare|drop).* [NC]
 RewriteRule ^(.*)$ - [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 8):

**GZip compression**

## GZip compression

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css  application/x-javascript
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
    BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
    BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 6):

### Redirects and pretty permalinks without mod_rewrite

```
# - script kiddies

Redirect permanent /admin.php http://localhost
Redirect permanent /_vti_bin http://localhost
Redirect permanent /css http://localhost
Redirect permanent /site http://localhost
Redirect permanent /s/ http://localhost
Redirect permanent /v/ http://localhost
Redirect permanent /html http://localhost
Redirect permanent /stil http://localhost
Redirect permanent /wp-content/cache.php http://localhost


# - stupid robots

Redirect permanent /sitemap.gz /sitemap.xml.gz
Redirect permanent /default.htm /
Redirect permanent /feeds/posts/default /feed/

- URL truncating

RedirectMatch Permanent ^/page/$ /
# /category/ and /comments/ to a TOC
RedirectMatch Permanent ^/(category|comments)/$ /uebersicht/

# Git only! :)
RedirectMatch Permanent \.(svn|cvs|SVN|CVS|bzr) http://localhost

# Bots searching for mobile versions
# see http://perishablepress.com/press/2010/04/26/stop-404-requests-for-mobile-versions-of-your-site/#comment-78105
RedirectMatch gone /mobi(le)?($|/)
RedirectMatch gone /iphone($|/)

# - 410

# Old feeds are dead
Redirect gone /2008/feed/
Redirect gone /2009/feed/
Redirect gone /2010/feed/

# stupid bots and browsers again

Redirect gone /crossdomain.xml
Redirect gone /labels.rdf
Redirect gone /.well-known
Redirect gone /parent-page
RedirectMatch gone .*/config$

# Pretty permalinks without mod_rewrite!
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
```

Comment: Is this way faster? I'm curious if there are any benefits for doing things this way

Comment: @DanGayle mod_rewrite works with regex and is therefore slightly slower. But you cannot use additional rules that you need in a multisite setup.

Answer (score 4):

ERRATA

```
#Jauntily show the admin’s email address in error message
SetEnv SERVER_ADMIN info@yoursite.com

#disable hotlinking of images with forbidden or custom image option
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://(www\.)?yoursite.com/.*$ [NC]
#RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ – [F]
#RewriteRule \.(gif|jpg|png)$ http://www.yoursite.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/bracker_thou_shalt_not_steal24.jpg [R,L]

#block referring domains
#RewriteEngine on
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} digg\.com [NC]
#RewriteRule .* – [F]

#Remove /category/ from your WordPress url
RewriteRule ^category/(.+)$ http://www.yourblog.com/$1 [R=301,L]

#Redirect visitors to a maintenance page
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/maintenance.html$
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} !^123\.123\.123\.123
RewriteRule $ /maintenance.html [R=302,L]

#auto-correct simple URL spelling mistakes
<IfModule mod_speling.c>
CheckSpelling On
</IfModule>

#better login
RewriteRule ^login$ http://example.com/wp-login.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Hey, cool. Didn't know about the mod_speling module. That should be handy!

Answer (score 3):

This is something more secured i hop you like this

```
# BEGIN Wordpress Browser Cache
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
    AddType text/css .css
    AddType application/x-javascript .js
    AddType text/x-component .htc
    AddType text/html .html .htm
    AddType text/richtext .rtf .rtx
    AddType image/svg+xml .svg .svgz
    AddType text/plain .txt
    AddType text/xsd .xsd
    AddType text/xsl .xsl
    AddType text/xml .xml
    AddType video/asf .asf .asx .wax .wmv .wmx
    AddType video/avi .avi
    AddType image/bmp .bmp
    AddType application/java .class
    AddType video/divx .divx
    AddType application/msword .doc .docx
    AddType application/vnd.ms-fontobject .eot
    AddType application/x-msdownload .exe
    AddType image/gif .gif
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .gzip
    AddType image/x-icon .ico
    AddType image/jpeg .jpg .jpeg .jpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-access .mdb
    AddType audio/midi .mid .midi
    AddType video/quicktime .mov .qt
    AddType audio/mpeg .mp3 .m4a
    AddType video/mp4 .mp4 .m4v
    AddType video/mpeg .mpeg .mpg .mpe
    AddType application/vnd.ms-project .mpp
    AddType application/x-font-otf .otf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database .odb
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart .odc
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula .odf
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics .odg
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation .odp
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet .ods
    AddType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text .odt
    AddType audio/ogg .ogg
    AddType application/pdf .pdf
    AddType image/png .png
    AddType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint .pot .pps .ppt .pptx
    AddType audio/x-realaudio .ra .ram
    AddType application/x-shockwave-flash .swf
    AddType application/x-tar .tar
    AddType image/tiff .tif .tiff
    AddType application/x-font-ttf .ttf .ttc
    AddType audio/wav .wav
    AddType audio/wma .wma
    AddType application/vnd.ms-write .wri
    AddType application/vnd.ms-excel .xla .xls .xlsx .xlt .xlw
    AddType application/zip .zip
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresByType text/css A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-javascript A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/x-component A31536000
    ExpiresByType text/html A3600
    ExpiresByType text/richtext A3600
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A3600
    ExpiresByType text/plain A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsd A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xsl A3600
    ExpiresByType text/xml A3600
    ExpiresByType video/asf A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/avi A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/bmp A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/java A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/divx A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/msword A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-fontobject A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-msdownload A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/gif A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-gzip A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/x-icon A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-access A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/midi A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/quicktime A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mp4 A31536000
    ExpiresByType video/mpeg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-project A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-otf A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.database A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/ogg A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/pdf A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/png A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-powerpoint A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/x-realaudio A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/svg+xml A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-tar A31536000
    ExpiresByType image/tiff A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/x-font-ttf A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wav A31536000
    ExpiresByType audio/wma A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-write A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/vnd.ms-excel A31536000
    ExpiresByType application/zip A31536000
</IfModule>
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
    <IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
        BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
        BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule mod_filter.c>
        AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css application/x-javascript text/x-component text/html text/richtext image/svg+xml text/plain text/xsd text/xsl text/xml image/x-icon
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
<FilesMatch "\.(css|js|htc|CSS|JS|HTC)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
    </IfModule>
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(html|htm|rtf|rtx|svg|svgz|txt|xsd|xsl|xml|HTML|HTM|RTF|RTX|SVG|SVGZ|TXT|XSD|XSL|XML)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
    </IfModule>
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
<FilesMatch "\.(asf|asx|wax|wmv|wmx|avi|bmp|class|divx|doc|docx|eot|exe|gif|gz|gzip|ico|jpg|jpeg|jpe|mdb|mid|midi|mov|qt|mp3|m4a|mp4|m4v|mpeg|mpg|mpe|mpp|otf|odb|odc|odf|odg|odp|ods|odt|ogg|pdf|png|pot|pps|ppt|pptx|ra|ram|svg|svgz|swf|tar|tif|tiff|ttf|ttc|wav|wma|wri|xla|xls|xlsx|xlt|xlw|zip|ASF|ASX|WAX|WMV|WMX|AVI|BMP|CLASS|DIVX|DOC|DOCX|EOT|EXE|GIF|GZ|GZIP|ICO|JPG|JPEG|JPE|MDB|MID|MIDI|MOV|QT|MP3|M4A|MP4|M4V|MPEG|MPG|MPE|MPP|OTF|ODB|ODC|ODF|ODG|ODP|ODS|ODT|OGG|PDF|PNG|POT|PPS|PPT|PPTX|RA|RAM|SVG|SVGZ|SWF|TAR|TIF|TIFF|TTF|TTC|WAV|WMA|WRI|XLA|XLS|XLSX|XLT|XLW|ZIP)$">
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Pragma "public"
        Header append Cache-Control "public, must-revalidate, proxy-revalidate"
    </IfModule>
    FileETag MTime Size
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
         Header set X-Powered-By "W3 Total Cache/0.9.2.4"
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
# END Wordpress Browser Cache
# BEGIN Wordpress Page Cache core
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^(.*\/)?Wordpress_rewrite_test$ $1?Wordpress_rewrite_test=1 [L]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} gzip
    RewriteRule .* - [E=Wordpress_ENC:_gzip]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} !=POST
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} =""
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =hubtank.com
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\/wp-admin\/|\/xmlrpc.php|\/wp-(app|cron|login|register|mail)\.php|\/feed\/|wp-.*\.php|index\.php) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (wp-comments-popup\.php|wp-links-opml\.php|wp-locations\.php) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} !(comment_author|wp-postpass|wordpress_\[a-f0-9\]\+|wordpress_logged_in) [NC]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !(W3\ Total\ Cache/0\.9\.2\.4) [NC]
    RewriteCond "%{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/wp-content/Wordpress/pgcache/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:Wordpress_UA}%{ENV:Wordpress_REF}%{ENV:Wordpress_SSL}.html%{ENV:Wordpress_ENC}" -f
    RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/Wordpress/pgcache/%{REQUEST_URI}/_index%{ENV:Wordpress_UA}%{ENV:Wordpress_REF}%{ENV:Wordpress_SSL}.html%{ENV:Wordpress_ENC}" [L]
</IfModule>
# END Wordpress Page Cache core
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```