# How to convert a plugin into a function

Tags: plugins, embed

How does one convert a plugin into a function especially when a plugin is so small that it has only one file?

Answer (score 1):

Plugins are just files with functions with special comments. You can take the complete code and copy it into your `functions.php`.

But … don’t.

Now you depend on the theme to get the plugin’s functionality. You cannot turn the plugin off separately. You have **zero benefit**, not even performance.

Don’t look too long at the [question 1567](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file) – 80% of the code snippets there are purely plugin material and do not belong into a `functions.php`.

Comment: Some people may want some functions to stick with their theme as these functions may be vital for the theme functionality itself.

Comment: @Maugly I agree. I have many functions in my themes too. :) But plugins are something different. If the theme works without the code, it is probably a plugin – and should be kept in the plugin directory.

Comment: Yup. I got your point. Probably just that **zero benefit** sounded too strict for me .)