# Error after editing functions.php

Tags: functions

I was making minor changes to `functions.php` file but just as I made the changes I  got an error, I used `FileZilla` and undo the function I added but now I am getting the following error,

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_action() in
>   /home/content/93/7877293/html/wordpress/wp-includes/functions.php on
>   line 51

I am sure that the file is now in its original condition. Can anyone help me by suggesting me how to deal with it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not supposed to edit `wp-includes/functions.php` but `wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php`.

Comment: @fahad - Use the "update" function from "Dashboard" and re-install Wordpress.

Comment: @scribu :) .. !!

Comment: Thanks alot. I got that functions file from wordpress installation. :)

Comment: That saved me from reinstalling the whole setup