# Extending the user profile

Tags: admin, dashboard, users, profiles

Is there any way that developing a Wordpress admin panel like this would be possible?

http://deanelliott.me/wp-content/uploads/account-backend.jpg

My client wants it to be displayed within the website template aswell.

I really don't want to have to outsource this, but I'm stumped as to how to achieve this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Yes you can extend user profile, remove user fields. Just use [this function] http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4125#4125

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second what @Viruthagiri said. You can also use the plugin [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/) if you want to hide the real WordPress control panel from your users and only show them their own profile/edit profile page, themed just like your site. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

For adding profile fields follow this [Justin Tadlock's post](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2009/09/10/adding-and-using-custom-user-profile-fields)

For removing some fields use this code

```
add_filter('user_contactmethods', 'no_contact_info');
function no_contact_info($contactmethods) {
    unset($contactmethods['aim']);
    unset($contactmethods['yim']);
    unset($contactmethods['jabber']);
    return $contactmethods;
}
```

But there are fields that will require jQuery to be removed

To fully style and put extra behaviors to the page use your own CSS and jQuery

```
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-profile.php', 'custom_profile_style' );
add_action( 'admin_print_scripts-user-edit.php', 'custom_profile_style' );
function custom_profile_style() {
    wp_register_style( 'custom_profile_css', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/profile.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom_profile_css' );
    wp_register_script( 'custom_profile_js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/profile.js' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'custom_profile_js' );
}
```

I am adding other contents to the page using this

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
    $('#wpbody-content').append('<iframe src="http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/" width="500" height="255" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>');
});
```