# Display SQL that wordpress is running

Tags: database

I am wanting to see the actual SQL that worpress is running to build certain pages, is there a debug method or some other way to outpout this or view it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use any one of these filters from /wp-includes/query.php

```
posts_where_request
posts_groupby_request
posts_join_request
posts_orderby_request
posts_distinct_request
posts_fields_request
post_limits_request
```

You can print certain parts of the query to the screen to see what's going on under the hood.

For instance, you can add this to your functions file:

```
add_filter('posts_where_request', 'foo_bar', 1, 10);
function foo_bar($where){
    print_r($where);
    return $where;
}
```

Comment: I also just found this debug file http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612 it shows all the queries ran, there sql and time to run and methods called