# Can't change permalink url after hitting 'ok' and 'update'

Tags: permalinks

I am trying to change some of the titles of my posts and their respective permalinks. After I edit the title and permalink and click 'ok', the permalink appears to have changed temporarily. However, when I click 'update', the permalink changes back to what it was originally.

Is there anything that may be preventing the change that I might have overlooked?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you somehow hidden/removed the slug metabox? (is something like this located in your functions.php?)

```
function remove_post_meta_box() {
    remove_meta_box('slugdiv', 'post', 'normal');
}
add_action('admin_menu', 'remove_post_meta_box');
```

If that's the case, it's causing the error.
There is a [Trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/18523) ticket for this already, but the only way to currently solve it is to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I changed the title of a page which was a "parent" to a few other pages - as you say the permalink kept going back to the original page title. I managed to update mine by going to the page listings, selecting "quick edit" of my parent page (rather than the "edit" option), then changed the "slug" to my new title - press update to save. This correctly saved the permalink name for my parent page and all the pages which were children. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue not being able to change the permalink, in my case: `http://mysite/action-2`. Whatever I did trying to change this to `http://mysite/action`, nothing worked. I had no pages or posts in trash so that was not causing the problem. There had to be a page occupying the permalink so i just typed in: `http://mysite/action` and there it was, a page containing an image, but there just wasn't any page within Wordpress with that image so I checked the media library and found the image that was presented on `http://mysite/action`. Since I didn't use that image I deleted it from the library and cleared the cache. when I checked the permalink on the page, I saw the permalink automatically had changed in the page title! Problem solved. :-)