# Preferred Method of debugging a wordpress SQL calls?

Tags: php, sql, debug, logging

What is your preferred method of debugging Wordpress Applications when writing custom behind-the-scenes SQL calls, etc. ?

Coming from a Rails background, I usually tail a log file that displays not only all the processes and views that are being seperately loaded into a template, but if there is an error, it will pin point the **exact** location of the error, with a suggested idea of what went wrong. I noticed that in WordPress, you can set up a debug.log file but it only shows a *very* barebones version of this, and rarely points to what actually is failing.

Any recommends?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turn on  `define( 'WP_DEBUG', true );`   ***and***   `define( 'SAVEQUERIES', true );` .

I prefer the format of the debug bar, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/ , which can be combined with the console, http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar-console/ .

This script is great for profiling, [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612)

There are some other plugins that might help, like [Debug Queries](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-queries/), but you probably going to have to use a debugger like xdebug to get more fine grained details.