# How to update feed only 2-3 times a week (for Feedburner email)?

Tags: functions, filters, actions, feedburner

So many of you know that Feedburner is a great (free) tool for sending out newsletters. The problem is that if you add content everyday, everyday emails will be sent out.

I'd like to control on functions.php how I could "update" the feed only 2-3 times a week, so emails from Feedburner would be sent only on these days. I thought about using something with:

`$d=date("D");
if($d=="Fri")...`

But I don't how this could be done with actions. Could someone help? =)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this function to delay the RSS feed as long as you desire. (example, 48 hours or every two days)

```
// delay feed update
function publish_later_on_feed($where) {
    global $wpdb;

    if (is_feed()) {
        // timestamp in WP-format
        $now = gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        // value for wait; + device
        $wait = '10'; // integer

        // http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff
        $device = 'MINUTE'; // MINUTE, HOUR, DAY, WEEK, MONTH, YEAR

        // add SQL-sytax to default $where
        $where .= " AND TIMESTAMPDIFF($device, $wpdb->posts.post_date_gmt, '$now') > $wait ";
    }
    return $where;
}
add_filter('posts_where', 'publish_later_on_feed');
```

source: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/1896/12086

Comment: I don't think this solves what question is asking. It will shift posts to appear in feed later, but it won't reduce count of times feed gets updated (essentially one per post, just at different time).

Comment: Yes, this is not suitable. I'm going to think about this and come up with a solution for those that want to use Feedburner as a week newsletter tool (send out only once).
Cheers anyways.