# sql for querying post and their category

Tags: query, mysql

I'm trying to query the wordpress database for the post and what category they belong in. Is there a sql query that I can use for this?

Thanks,

Comment: Are you trying to do this inside of WordPress or outside of it?

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific post in WordPress, you can use the [`get_post()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post) function and [`get_the_category()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) to get the categories associated with it. You can then use the code found in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/4612#4612) to dump the SQL queries used.

```
<?php
$post_ID = 7;
$the_post = get_post( $post_ID );
$the_category = get_the_category( $post_ID );
```

Answer (score 0):

To get a specific post in WordPress, you can use the `get_post()` function and `get_the_category()` to get the categories associated with it. You can then use the code found in this answer to dump the SQL queries used: `$GLOBALS['wpdb']->last_query`.