# Determine which template-{slug}.php is being loaded

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

I am trying to make a personal plugin that does specific things based on what is loaded. In this example, in my action method I want to perform one function if the currently loading page is using the `template-blog.php` template, if it's a single blog post (loading `single.php` do  a second function, anything else do a 3rd function

I am not quite sure what method I need to use, and so far Google is not pulling up the right methods. I have been trying get_current_template(), get_template() get_page_template(), but none of them pull the stuff I am looking for above.

Comment: google template_include then

Comment: [This answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/3848/8105) seems to be exactly what you're looking for, does it not?

Comment: In addition to dalbeab's answer, I just want to say that if you want to style the blog page (i.e. the page on which all the posts get output), then you should use home.php instead of a custom page template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `body_class()` on the body tag would probably be the easiest way to tell which template is in use.

```
<body <?php body_class(); ?>>
```

Depending on which page you are on, it will output similar to this

```
<body class="page page-id-10 page-template-default logged-in">
```

Where `page-template-default` is the template in use. It's also useful for blog posts and custom post types.