# How can I determine what php files are being called by a given WP page?

Tags: debug

I'd like to debug some WordPress functionality, but to do so I need to know where to find the php file that is executing on a given page. How can I set up something that will tell me what php files (or functions, objects) are being called to generate a given page? I'm using a ridiculous amount of plugins, and I have a complicated theme structure, so it's not really practical to insert debug messages into every single php file I have, like the answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/97744/determine-which-template-slug-php-is-being-loaded) suggests.

Answer (score 6):

There's a [native PHP function `get_included_files()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) for that.

Simply attach it to an action on the hook from where you want to know it. The first one is `muplugins_loaded` and the last accessible on is `shutdown`.

```
add_action( 'muplugins_loaded', function()
{
    $files = get_included_files();
    foreach ( $files as $f )
        echo $f.'<br>';

    // or...
    var_dump( $files );
}
```

Comment: Wasn't my question but thanks, completely forgot about this function.

Comment: Well, it was "to find the php file that is executing on a given page" and that is what the answer provides. I'm not completely sure how to answer your question in any other way.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure there is a generic answer to this question but my advice would be to:

1. [Enable debugging](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/95982/where-do-i-get-bug-information-to-add-to-a-question/95983#95983)
2. Learn to drive [grep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep)
3. Run [`debug_backtrace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) for a more detailed history of what has occurred up to some point in a page load or function call-- `var_dump(debug_backtrace());`