# Static posts page with home.php

Tags: posts, customization, pages

For my website, I am using a static home page page Home (template front-page.php) and for posts- page News (template home.php)

I need to show all the post titles and exceprts on that page News (templ. home.php), but also show the original title and the_content from that page News itself.

This code below while statement shows all the posts, which is good, but the top `the_title` also shows the title from the first post, not from the News page itself.

How to achieve what I need?

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    the_title();
          the_content();
    ?>

<?php if(have_posts()) while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

        <?php
        the_title();
        ?>

        <?php
        the_content();
        ?>

    <?php
    endwhile;
    ?>  

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your problem. I am unable to get anything :/

Comment: tried a bit clarify :)

Comment: Check out the code in **EDIT 2** of my answer [here](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/147911/31545). Seems that is what you are looking for. Just modify as needed

Answer (score 3):

`get_queried_object()` stores the original object that was found as a match for the permalink.

It's the WP_Post object of your News Page

```
$news_page = get_queried_object();
echo $news_page->post_title;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  <?php get_header(); ?>

    <?php
    the_title();
          the_content();
    ?>
```

Replace with

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<?php
  $page_id = $wp_query->query_vars['page_id'];

  echo get_the_title($page_id);
  echo apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content($page_id));
?>
```

Comment: echo $page_id returns 0  :/

Comment: $page_object = get_queried_object();
$page_id     = get_queried_object_id();
Did the trick

Comment: `echo $page_id returns 0 :/`
fixed

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did on a recent site:

```
$blog_page_object      = get_queried_object();
$blog_page_title       = $blog_page_object -> post_title;
$blog_page_description = apply_filters('the_content', $blog_page_object -> post_content );

?>

<h1><?php echo( $blog_page_title ) ?></h1>
<?php echo( $blog_page_description ) ?>
```