# Whats causing image quality to be degraded?

Tags: images

I'm currently developing a site - http://www.shoplikeits1999.com/ - and I've been struggling to figure out why image quality is deteriorating in the "product grid" layout (below Newest/Popular/Price/Categories).

The original image size when I upload is 460px by 300px. The images in the product grid are set to a proportional size - 394px by 257px, so I would not expect a reduction in image quality, but as you can see, they're somewhat fuzzy. I've been spinning my wheels for hours trying to figure out why this is happening.

Can anyone provide insight?

Comment: Awesome! ImageMagick did the trick. Also I'd like to note that even with ImageMagick, image quality still sucks on older browsers. Guess there's not much I can do about that. Thanks all for your help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Best Collection of Code for your functions.php file](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file)

Comment: If *any* of the answer was helpful to you, then consider accepting it. See »[What should I do when someone answers my question](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)?« and/or »[Why is voting important](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote)?«, more information about the [wordpress.se] model is available at the [help].

Answer (score 1):

Some of your images are png: http://www.shoplikeits1999.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/Harvest_Moon_64_Coverart.png

And that image not `460px by 300px` and is being stretched to fit the grid.

I would guess that you need to be more careful in which images you upload and how you process the images prior to uploading.

Comment: The png image you referenced is not a product, it's a blog post, which doesn't appear in the grid below. I've uploaded JPEGs for the product images at 460x300. It looks like it creates a 400x261 image because that's the image referenced when I inspect the element. Note that I never actually uploaded a 400x261 version. But that 400x261 version appears fine when you "view image", but something degrades it when it appears on the grid.

Answer (score 0):

This could be a number of things, but very likely, you have a function either in your functions.php or plugin folder that sets the compression percentage of JPEG files (affects all of your image sizes beside `full`)

For testing, in your `functions.php` file, set the JPEG compression to full (100%):

```
function jpeg_quality_callback($arg) {
    return (int)100;
}

add_filter('jpeg_quality', 'jpeg_quality_callback');
```

If I am not mistaken, WP auto sets compression to 90%.

Comment: I added this in the child theme functions.php, unfortunately it did not seem to have an effect.

Answer (score 0):

As said before in the comment, besides as @CristineCooper said the image quality and as @shanebp said the stretching issue, using *ImageMagick* - has to be available at your server - instead of GD gives generally *better image quality* results.