# Is my child theme working properly

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

A few days ago I created a child theme of my theme zerif lite. Everything is looking good and there is no problem at all.

I just want to know are the created `functions.php` and `style.css` files correct or not. And I added some optimized files in my child theme which are already exist in parent theme (Unoptimized but same files), but i am in doubt that same files are loading 2 times from parent and child theme. I want to be sure that same files not load 2 times.

This is my style.css of child theme:

```
/*
Theme Name:   Zerif Lite Child
Theme URI:    http:/only4gamers.ml
Description:  Zerif Lite Child Theme
Author:       Md Umar
Author URI:   http:/only4gamers.ml
Template:     zerif-lite
Version:      1.0.0
License:      GNU General Public License v2 or later License URI:  http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html
Tags:         light, dark, two-columns,right-sidebar, responsive-layout, accessibility-ready Text Domain:  zerif-lite-child
*/
```

and this is function file of child theme:

```
<?php  
function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {  

    $parent_style = 'zerif-style';  

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );  
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',  
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',  
        array( $parent_style ),  
        wp_get_theme()->get('Version')  
    );  
}  
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );  
?>
```

I am new to wordpress and don't know much about coding. Any improvement in my style and function file is highly appreciated.

Comment: Did you mean function or function**s**.php?

Comment: i updated my post and added more details.

Comment: Additionally to @TomJNowell's answer, I suggest you reading https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file, this may give you more references.

Comment: thank you so much bro, but there is no need to make it more complicated. as i already said i am new in this coding world and don't know much about coding. this question is related to child themes. I copy above codes from here  https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes  and i just simply copy and paste codes without much modification. if anyone here using child themes then he/she can easily understand my question.

Answer (score 3):

There's a simple way to test:

- add `wp_die('it works');` to `functions.php`, if you see `it works` on every page, then it's worked
- add a silly CSS rule to `style.css`, e.g. `body { border: 100px solid pink; }`, if your pages now have a 100 pixel pink border then your stylesheet is working

**If it works, then you did it correctly**, if you didn't do it the correct way, it wouldn't work.

Otherwise, the only thing's I'd note are that:

- it's `functions.php` not `function.php`
- avoid closing PHP tags in functions.php, PHP will auto-add them if needed, and it prevents a common mistake with whitespace after the tag
- `my_theme` is a very generic prefix, you should pick something more unique