# Display Custom Post Type Archive content with Shortcode

Tags: custom-post-types, shortcode, custom-post-type-archives

So I've created a custom post type filled with Advanced Custom Fields only.
There is no "content".

I've created a `single-custom.php`, `content-custom.php` and `archive-custom.php`.

All looking nice and working perfect.

What I would like to achieve is to create a shortcode (I believe) for the `archive-custom.php`, so I can display the content of the `archive-custom.php` content on another part of my website, let's say on two different pages, with additional content.

At first i thought i create a short code for the custom post type it self by this example: [Themed custom loop using shortcodes](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/1567/best-collection-of-code-for-your-functions-php-file/5741#5741)

But it's getting rather a very long short code. And everything I've solved before in `content-custom.php`, I have to start over in `functions.php` and "re-div-ify" it in the shortcode.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you need a bunch of divs etc duplicated in both `archive-custom.php` and the shortcode. Identify those divs, and move them into a new template file in your theme, e.g. in `part-archive-custom.php`.
Then, delete them from `archive-custom.php` and add a call to `get_template_part('part-archive-custom');` instead.

Do the same inside your shortcode.