# Adding custom Javascript to the head tag in Admin

Tags: admin, plugins, customization

I am writing a plugin for the back end but I need to add javascript that is created in a for loop to the head of the page.

How do i do this?

Steve

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is here *(Look for the section entitled "Load Scripts only on pages where needed"):*

- [**What is the best way to add custom javascript files to the site?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site/562#562)