# Pre-fill fields with content from outside when creating a new post

Tags: wp-admin, posts, custom-content

I'd like to find a way to fill some of the fields from the `/wp-admin/post-new.php` page from an external source.

It works for the title: loading `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_title=title1` fills the title input with `title1`.

You get the idea, what would be great is something like `/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_title=title1&content=content1&tags=tag1,tag2&cat=cat1,cat2`... so that when I arrive on the `post-new.php` with most fields already filled from an outside script.

I would need to fill in custom fields as well.

How can I do that? What's the best option? A full external script that connects to the base my himself and run insert queries? A plugin? If so, do you have some suggestions?

Answer (score 11):

An empty post is created by [`get_default_post_to_edit()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-admin/includes/post.php#L351). This function reads the `post_title`, `content` and `excerpt` values in the `$_REQUEST` array, and also filters them through `default_title`, `default_content` and `default_excerpt`.

By default this function only returns a "fake" `$post` object, but if the `$create_in_db` parameter is set to `true`, it is actually saved in the database with the `post_status` set to `auto-draft`.

[This parameter is set in `post-new.php`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.0.5/wp-admin/post-new.php#L50), which means you can hook into `wp_insert_post` and save extra stuff, like tags, from the `$_REQUEST` array or from an external source. A very simple example:

```
add_action( 'load-post-new.php', 'wpse8650_post_new' );
function wpse8650_post_new()
{
    add_action( 'wp_insert_post', 'wpse8650_wp_insert_post_default' );
}

function wpse8650_wp_insert_post_default( $post_id )
{
    add_post_meta( $post_id, 'wpse8650_meta_key', $_REQUEST['meta_value'] );
    wp_set_post_tags( $post_id, $_REQUEST['tags']) );
}
```

This works because the custom fields and post tags are read again from the database (or the cache) when building the page, and we do this before these metaboxes are displayed.

Comment: i just tried with adding `die($post_id);` its not even tell $post_id.. Can someone check this please? is it still working on 3.3?

Answer (score 3):

If this is to add end-users then maybe the easiest thing to do is to create a jQuery script to assign the values.  Here's how to parse the URL:

- [**Get QueryString values with jQuery**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery)

And here's how to add Javascript in WordPress:

- [**What is the best way to add custom javascript files to the site?**](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site/562#562)

Finally, just view source in the WordPress edit screen to see the names of the input fields and then this shows how to use jQuery to assign values:

- [**How to get and set form element values with jQuery**](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/jquery-get-set-form-values/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mike's answer, you can also use WordPress' XML-RPC server to do external posting. It depends on what you're trying to do.