# Add new page with preselected parent

Tags: pages

I do not want my clients to select a parent page from the drop down list, when creating a child page, so I would like to create a link on the dashboard which links to "add new page" - but with a preselected parent page.

Is this possible? And if not, then is there a way to change the default parent from "(no parent)" to a parent of my choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

welcome to WPSE!

[This answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/8653/12615) from Mike Schinkel was useful to find a <strike>solution</strike><sup>*</sup> for [Get QueryString values with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-values-with-jquery). `*`<sup>(not used anymore, a simple `$_GET` does it)</sup>

It's also worth noting that, in that same answer, Mike also links to this other important Question: [What is the best way to add custom javascript files to the site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-best-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site/562#562)

That being said, the following code does the trick. It doesn't use `admin_enqueue_scripts` -best practice-, and instead is printing it directly in the admin footer...

Add this code to your theme's `functions.php` and make your custom link to "Add New Page" like this: `http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&the_id=28`, being `the_id` the ID of the desired parent page.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'pre_select_parent_wpse_56952' );

function pre_select_parent_wpse_56952() 
{
    // Check if adding new page 
    if( !isset($_GET['post_type']) || 'page' != $_GET['post_type'] ) 
        return;

    // Check for pre-selected parent
    if( !isset($_GET['the_id']) || empty( $_GET['the_id'] ) ) 
        return;

    // There is a pre-selected value for the correct post_type, proceed with script
    $the_id = $_GET['the_id'];
    ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) 
        {
            $('#parent_id').val(<?php echo $the_id; ?>);
        });
        </script>
    <?php
}
```

Comment: Wow!

You sir, are a modern day hero!

I can not thank you enough for this!

Comment: could this be used for preselecting page templates as well?

Comment: Yes, quite easily, you only have to analyze the HTML code, check the ID and values used, and add the correspondent two lines of Javascript (`template_id`)... Give it a try but ping me in case of troubles (i'm on the iphone right now;)

Comment: Similar code for templates in  my answer to this question: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/53486/how-to-add-or-remove-metabox-each-page-separately/

Comment: hi I am trying to do the same for a new project - but with preseleted for posts, do you think this could be done? :)

Comment: Hi, Kasper, pre-selected what? Posts don't have parents, poor orphans... Jokes aside, just change the `post_type` and do your thing. Using the browser console, you can play live with jQuery until you find the correct target/action. Looking at this code now, I think it can be simplified, I'll give it another go. Anyway, maybe you should open a new Q.

Comment: hey, thanks for your reply! missed a word, for some reason - it should have said pre selected CATEGORIES (the foster parents of posts?).
I have used your previous code for a dozen of projects already :D

Comment: You can play with [this code](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/78781/12615) :P

Comment: I never really got this working with template_id - But I have a project know which requires it. I am looking for a solution like with the parent page, where I can create a link like http://example.com/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=page&the_id=28 - but for a template. How can I do this? :)

Comment: Happy new year! I just found your old awesome solution to this problem again. But now I am working on a project where I need the page to "know" that it is a child of page X before I publish it. At the moment, with your code, it does not know it before I click "publish".
I have some field which I display based on page parent, that I would like to show before publishing - if a parent is pre-selected - and hide if not.
Hope you can help! :)