# Solutions for generating dynamic javascript / CSS

Tags: theme-development, css, javascript

Let's say you need to generate javascript or CSS code that depends on the current context.

For example you have a form on the homepage that fires an ajax request on submit, and a different form on the single page. Or in the case of CSS, you want to create a theme that allows its users to build their own layout, change colors etc.

Solutions I see so far:

1. Include the code in the head section of the document (or at the end in case of JS)
2. Do a special request that outputs the code, like *site.com?get_assets*. This is slow because WP gets loaded twice.
3. Store it in temporary files for a certain amount of time, and load it from there. Not very reliable for public themes or plugins.
4. Javascript only - make it static by putting it into a normal file that gets loaded every time. In this case you would have to make your code handle any situation

Do you know others? Which way would you go?

Comment: one issue I encountered with solution 1 is caching by the browser, the code does not get refreshed on page reload.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One additional option, depending on the kind of parameters you need to pass in. Let's call it (2a). You can also create PHP scripts which output dynamically-generated `text/css` or `text/javascript` rather than `text/html`, and provide them the data that they need using GET parameters rather than by loading up WordPress. Of course this only works if you need to pass in a relatively small number of relatively compact parameters. So, for instance, say you need to pass in only the URL of a post or the directory of a file or similar, you can do something like this:

In header.php:

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php print get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); 
 ?>/fancy-js.php?foo=bar&amp;url=<?php print urlencode(get_permalink($post->ID)); ?>"></script>
```

In fancy-js.php:

```
 <?php
 header("Content-type: text/javascript");
 ?>
 foo = <?php print json_encode($_GET['foo']); ?>;
 url = <?php print json_encode($_GET['url']); ?>;
```

etc.

But this only allows you access to the data directly passed in the GET parameters; and it will only work if the number of things you need to pass in is relatively small, and the representation of those things relatively compact. (Basically  handful of string or numeric values -- a username, say, or a directory; not a list of all of a user's recent posts or something like that.)

As for which one of these options is the best -- I don't know; that depends on your use case. Option (1) has the merit of being simple, and clearly allowing you access to any WordPress data you could possibly need, without the performance hit of loading WordPress twice. It's almost certainly what you should do unless you have a strong reason not to (e.g. due to the size of the stylesheet or script that you need to use).

If the size becomes big enough to cause a problem in terms of the weight of your one page, then you can try out (2) or (2a).

Or else -- this is probably the better idea -- you can try to separate out the parts of the script or the stylesheet that actually make use of the dynamic data from the parts that can be specified statically. Ssay you have a stylesheet that needs to be passed a directory from WordPress in order to set a background parameter for the #my-fancy element. You could put all of this into the head element:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #my-fancy-element {
      background-image: url(<?php print get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>images/fancy.png);
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 12pt;
      /* ... KB and KB of additional styles ... */
 }
 #another-fancy-element {
     /* ... KB and KB of additional styles ... */
 }
 /* ... KB and KB of additional styles ... */
 </style>
```

But why would you need to do that? There's only one line here that depends on data from WordPress. Better to split out only the lines that depend on WordPress:

```
 <style type="text/css">
 #my-fancy-element {
      background-image: url(<?php print get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>images/fancy.png);
 }
 </style>
```

Put everything else in a static stylesheet that you load in with a standard link element (style.css or whatever):

```
 #my-fancy-element {
      /* background-image provided dynamically */
      padding: 20px;
      margin: 20px;
      font-weight: bold;
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 12pt;
      /* ... KB and KB of additional styles ... */
 }
 #another-fancy-element {
     /* ... KB and KB of additional styles ... */
 }
 /* ... KB and KB of additional styles ... */
```

And let the cascade do the work.

The same goes for JavaScript: rather than doing this:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 // Here comes a huge function that uses WordPress data:
 function my_huge_function () {
     // Do a million things ...

     jQuery('#my-fancy').append('<a href="'+<?php json_encode(get_permalink($GLOBALS['post']->ID)); ?>+'">foo</a>);

     // Do a million more things ...

     my_other_function(<?php print json_encode(get_userdata($GLOBALS['post']->post_author); ?>);
 }

 function my_other_function (user) {
     // Do a million things ...
 }
 </script>
```

Instead put something like this in the head element:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
 var WordPressPostData = {
 url: <?php print json_encode(get_permalink($GLOBALS['post']->ID)); ?>,
 author: <?php print json_encode(get_userdata($GLOBALS['post']->post_author)); ?>
 }
 </script>
```

And then drop the rest into a static JavaScript file, rewriting the my_huge_function() and my_other_function() to make use of the globals WordPressPostData.url and WordPressPostData.author.

40K of CSS or 40K of JS can almost always be split into <1K that actually depends on dynamic data, and the rest, which can be specified in a static external file and then recombined using either the cascade (for CSS) or globally-accessible variables (globals, DOM elements, or whatever other cubby-hole you prefer, for JS).

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: Just a small addition: in case of JS, we can use [wp_localize_sciprt](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) to add dynamic variables.

Answer (score 6):

The dynamic CSS case is fairly simple.

Just create a function that outputs the dynamic CSS definitions inside of `<style type="text/css"></style>` tags, and then hook that function into `wp_print_styles`. e.g.

```
<?php
function mytheme_dynamic_css() {
    $options = get_option( 'mytheme_options' );
    ?>
    <style type="text/css">
    /* Dynamic H1 font family */
    h1 { font-family: <?php echo $options['h1_font_family']; ?>;
    </style>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_print_styles', 'mytheme_dynamic_css' );
?>
```

Or, let's say you have pre-configured color schemes; you can enqueue the appropriate stylesheet according to the current user setting:

```
<?php
function mytheme_enqueue_colorscheme_stylesheet() {
    $options = get_option( 'mytheme_options' );
    $color_scheme = $options['color_scheme'];
    wp_enqueue_style( $colorscheme, get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/' . $color_scheme . '.css' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_enqueue_colorscheme_stylesheet' );
?>
```

Note that, in this case, the function hooks into `wp_enqueue_scripts`, since WordPress does not have a `wp_enqueue_styles` action hook.

Comment: same as 1). This is what I'm doing now, but if you have like 40K of CSS you get a bulky html document

Comment: But those 40K of CSS have to be output *somewhere*, right? And, definitely the same as #1, but is the **right way** to inject dynamic CSS in WordPress. :)

Answer (score 2):

I was thinking that for a while now. Your question make me get back to it. **Not sure it is a good idea or not, so i would like experts comments on that.**

**What if** i [write the javascript/css file via php](http://www.css-resources.com/write-js-file-with-php.html) when admin saving the data. It will be a one time write until user changes the layout again (which user may not do too often). That way we are accessing the database for the user settings only once when user saving data.

After writing the file it will be a regular javascript/css files so we dont have to call database everytime the theme loads.

One question that need answered: **What will happen when a visitor try to access the site in the instant when php writing the file?**

Let me know what you think.

Comment: If you generate those files in `wp-content/uploads` (the only directory guaranteed to be writable from WP code), it could be a viable approach. I think even WP Core uses this technique for one js file.

Comment: The drawback is that it's not really dynamic, i.e. it's the same for everyone on all pages. For each variation, you would have to generate a new file. It's still a good approach for theme/plugin options, as you mentioned.

Comment: @scribu: yes its true. it can be a mess for something like. if we give users a customized profile page and have to write files each one of them. But it might be a good approach for something like if we do a visual website maker (drag and drop) where user changes the colors and add various effects (as of this question) etc.. and may be combined with WPMU ;)

Answer (score 1):

For small pieces of scripts, which you may not want to include in a separate file, for instance because they are generated dynamically, WordPress 4.5 and further offers [`wp_add_inline_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/). This function basically latches the script to another script. Let's say, for instance, that you are developing a theme and want your customer to be able to insert his own scripts (like Google Analytics or AddThis) through the options page. [Example](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/244527/75495).

For styles there's [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style), which basically works the same. You would use it, for instance, to loop through all your customizer mods, and gather them in a string called `$all_mods`, which you would then add like this to your main stylesheet:

```
if (!empty($all_mods)) wp_add_inline_style ('main-style', $all_mods);
```

Answer (score -2):

**Create a dynamic JS.php file and feed important query_vars to it.** Those variables in `$_GET` will help the file determine context and in it you can cache and use `readfile()` for future requests... do whatever.

Just make sure that file loads the `wp-load.php` before anything else, so you have access to WP functions. Use relative path to current folder `(dirname(__FILE__))` or just digg descending in the folder structure to locate `wp-load.php` regardless of plugin placement.

#### Code to seek wp-load.php from anywhere

```
// Ensure single declaration of function!
if(!function_exists('wp_locate_loader')):
    /**
     * Locates wp-load.php looking backwards on the directory structure.
     * It start from this file's folder.
     * Returns NULL on failure or wp-load.php path if found.
     * 
     * @author EarnestoDev
     * @return string|null
     */
    function wp_locate_loader(){
        $increments = preg_split('~[\\\\/]+~', dirname(__FILE__));
        $increments_paths = array();
        foreach($increments as $increments_offset => $increments_slice){
            $increments_chunk = array_slice($increments, 0, $increments_offset + 1);
            $increments_paths[] = implode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR, $increments_chunk);
        }
        $increments_paths = array_reverse($increments_paths);
        foreach($increments_paths as $increments_path){
            if(is_file($wp_load = $increments_path.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.'wp-load.php')){
                return $wp_load;
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
endif;
// Now try to load wp-load.php and pull it in
$mt = microtime(true);
if(!is_file($wp_loader = wp_locate_loader())){
    header("{$_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']} 403 Forbidden");
    header("Status: 403 Forbidden");
    echo 'Access denied!'; // Or whatever
    die;
}
require_once($wp_loader); // Pull it in
unset($wp_loader); // Cleanup variables
```

Cheers, Scribu!

**PS**: For complicated structures where folders don't follow the normal WP decremental structure, parent plugins can share informations with directly accessible files. A parent plugin that comes with a dynamic PHP file that renders CSS/JS can write into a file the `realpath()` of the `wp-load.php` and the standalone file can use that. This would be an issue for 0.1% of WP users. I think those who move folders and don't follow the normal structure know what they're doing and can probably PIMP plugins that need to load `wp-load.php` directly.

Comment: Cute! Haters, please append explanations. Enlighten me. Thanks ;) xoxo

Comment: It's bad practice to include `wp-load.php` from a theme or plugin file, since the `wp-content` and/or `plugins`  directories could be anywhere relative to the root WP dir. Remember WP_CONTENT_DIR and WP_PLUGINS_DIR.

Comment: @scribu Have you any idea on how do loop down the directory structure and locate wp-load.php? OMG! Dude, seriously...! I edited the post. Enjoy. (it's never bad practice if you know what you're doing)

Comment: I didn't need the code example, but thanks anyway. Besides being inneficient, what if the root wp dir is in `/var/www/wp/` and wp-content is in `/var/www/wp-content/`? That's a common setup when you want to keep the core directory clean.

Comment: @scribu 0.0003 microtimed. I knew you was gonna say that. What if? What if the world ends before tomorrow ever comes? You can search the folder structure recursively and store the path for future use. It's that easy. WHAT IF? "Daca si cu Parca se plimbau pe-o barca. Daca Daca nu era, Parca parca se-neca."

Comment: @scribu And the standalone file can collaborate with a parent plugin. The parent plugin can store the wp-load.php in the folder where it's located and the dynamic js generator can read it from there. Simple...

Comment: Yes, the parent plugin approach could work. Write it up in your answer and I'll remove my downvote. PS: This site is in english; you might have problems if you continue to leave remarks in Romanian.

Comment: @scribu I really hope I don't look like I care... because I don't... care! At all.

Comment: Cut the attitude. Manual core load is viable technique, but far from good first pick for most things. No one doubts that you can make it work. Votes are about quality of your answer, not your brain.

Comment: @Rarst I'm still not sure what's wrong with my answer. Yeap... still waiting, anticipating, withstanding hating.

Comment: Amazing. I can't downvote my own post... just tried. Darn!