# Add JavaScript in admin in custom plugin

Tags: admin, javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the preferred way to add custom javascript files to the site?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site)

I was reading few posts here about this, but all answers are about wp_enqueue_script or something. I'm looking for solution to embed custom JavaScript variable (created by json_encode()) in footer or in header but in admin add_action 'wp_footer' and 'wp_head' are not called. How to embed custom code - not include file.

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site/562#562

Comment: A completely detailed answer in the link @BrianFegter posted.

Answer (score 1):

Admin area has its own hooks in header and footer, respectively:

```
do_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', $hook_suffix);
do_action("admin_print_styles-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_styles');
do_action("admin_print_scripts-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_print_scripts');
do_action("admin_head-$hook_suffix");
do_action('admin_head');
```

and

```
do_action('admin_footer', '');
do_action('admin_print_footer_scripts');
do_action("admin_footer-" . $GLOBALS['hook_suffix']);
```