# Is it ever okay to include inline CSS in plugins?

Tags: plugin-development, css, customization, wp-enqueue-style

Normally in a plugin I would add styles using wp_enqueue_style. However, I am currently creating a plugin that only needs a few lines of CSS and I am wondering if it might be better to serve the styles inline to save a request. Obviously there are many advantages to using wp_enqueue_style, but are they worth the extra request for such a small piece of CSS? Is there any accepted 'best practice' in this area?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

TL;DR; `Enqueue`

**Using external stylesheet**

- *PRO:* All your styles are in one spot.
- *PRO:* Reduces web page coding.
- *PRO:* Easier to maintain the plugin.
- *PRO:* Can use hooks to alter location of the file.
- *PRO:* Can use hooks to unqueue the file.
- *PRO:* Can use minify styles automatically.
- *CON:* Might add extra HTTP request (can be overcome).

**Using inline styles**

- *PRO:* Can directly see the style applied.
- *PRO:* No extra HTTP requests.
- *CON:* Can not use hooks to alter the styles.
- *CON:* Can not use hooks to unqueue the styles.
- *CON:* Can not minify styles at all.
- *CON:* **Need** !important to override style

Normally I would say: Sure, if you are the only one using it, go ahead and do it inline. But you are talking about a **plugin** which means the code will be **public** so aim for extendibility. Right now you only have a few lines of styling:

- *CON:* What if that few become more?
- *CON:* What if someone extends your plugin?
- *CON:* What if someone wants to alter it?
- *CON:* What if someone searches for it in css files?
- *CON:* What if someone wants to minify it automatically?

Therefore, enqueue. (Preferably Conditionally only if the plugin needs it.)
[The same applies to JavaScript](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site). (But that should be included in the footer if possible.)

Comment: Is it okay to use inline styles on the backend?

Comment: @bungeshea If someone is going to change your plugin, they might want to change the backend too right ;) Just make sure you only enqueue the script when on the backend. For example: `function _your_enqueue( $hook )` can test $hook to see if your on your options page. Alternatively you can use `current_screen()` for __simpler__ properties. The thing is, you ARE allowed to do this, but the general use is a plugin consists of a .php file for serverside code and may or may not have images, .js and .css files.

Comment: You note that the extra http request can be overcome - can you clarify this?

Comment: You can't, but the user of the plugin can. There are several plugins and functions written to, just before the page is outputted, get ALL the enqueued styles and add them to a minified, combined file. No matter how many CSS files you add, the viewer will only see one. Same for javascript. However, this is in your case not your 'problem'. It's optimization that is not needed and imho, the extra HTTP request kinda falls short against all the PRO's.

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate that your answer points out the problem of not being able to dequeue inline styles as one of the primary points against it. What about the case of a plugin that absolutely needs the styles to function? I suppose someone may still want to remove the styles on specific pages or alter the styles.

Comment: About the last sentence - AFAIK styles  should be output in the header not the footer

Comment: @MarkKaplun, you are correct. I usually write this post about both CSS and JS. Let me edit that.

Comment: @Dustin if it absolutely needs it to function, you should still allow the user to break the Plugin. Just make sure you enqueue it in the first place. If the user knows how to dequeue a style, lets assume that he also knows he is breaking the plugin by doing so. But that's a leap of faith I think we should all take.

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to answer and I am really not sure if there is an official answer.

I understand the sentiment about saving a request but inline style pretty much always wins. A theme or end user will have a hard time altering your CSS.

With that in mind, I think I'd do this in a publicly released plugin...

1. if the CSS is absolutely critical to the ***functioning*** of the plugin, as is the case with slideshows, for example.
2. Or, if I also included a filter in the plugin that allows the inline CSS to be altered or removed.