# Output dynamic_sidebar_params in wp_head

Tags: filters, widgets, wp-head

I have created a custom widget with a color picker field. Currently there are two ways to output the color picker value for this widget:

1. Inline style.
2. Using the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter. With this option i can output the color value inside the style tags, but it will be outputted inside the widget HTML.

Both methods have their own well known disadvantages.

The best solution would be to use the `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter and make the output in the head part of the document using the `wp_head` action. The thing is that i can't find a way to make it happen.

Have someone worked with a similar situation?

Comment: This is a common issue. Once WP starts evaluating widgets, the html for the head already has been generated. You cannot add anything anymore using `wp_head`. What you could do is have your plugin read the widget settings and output them in the head, before the evaluation of the actual widget class.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it as well, find the widget id and pass it via the wp_head action, but still no success. Could you please share a an example of such solution, if you have one?

Answer (score 0):

Going through its normal proceedings Wordpress will already have evaluated `wp_head` by the time it gets to the widgets. The `dynamic_sidebar_params` filter will only be called then as well, so it will also be of little help to get your `css` in the head. [Here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/193167/adding-inline-styles-from-a-widget)'s something I wrote about this issue earlier.

To include information from widget settings in the head, you would have to access the settings directly with a function that is activated on the `init` action. **Beware** that I have not tested the following and don't know if any complications could arise.

All widget settings are stored in a global variable called `$wp_registered_widgets`, which is sadly not very well documented (presumably because you're not supposed to mess with it). The datastructure is something like this ([props @shibashake](http://shibashake.com/wordpress-theme/wordpress-widget-system), but it might be changed without warning):

```
Array (
    [archives-1] => Array (
            [name] => Archives
            [id] => archives-1
            [callback] => Array (
                    [0] => WP_Widget_Archives Object (
                            [id_base] => archives
                            [name] => Archives
                            [widget_options] => Array (
                                    [classname] => widget_archive
                                    [description] => A monthly archive of your blog&#8217;s posts )

                            [control_options] => Array (
                                    [id_base] => archives )

                            [number] => 1
                            [id] => archives-1
                            [updated] => 
                            [option_name] => widget_archives )

                    [1] => display_callback )

            [params] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [number] => -1 ) 
                )

            [classname] => widget_archive
            [description] => A monthly archive of your blog&#8217;s posts )

    [text-8] => Array (
            [name] => Text
            [id] => text-8
            [callback] => Array (
                    [0] => WP_Widget_Text Object (
                            [id_base] => text
                            [name] => Text
                            [widget_options] => Array (
                                    [classname] => widget_text
                                    [description] => Arbitrary text or HTML )

                            [control_options] => Array (
                                    [id_base] => text
                                    [width] => 400
                                    [height] => 350 )

                            [number] => 8
                            [id] => text-8
                            [updated] => 
                            [option_name] => widget_text )

                    [1] => display_callback )

            [params] => Array (
                    [0] => Array (
                            [number] => 8 )
                 )

            [classname] => widget_text
            [description] => Arbitrary text or HTML )
... )
```

Now, you could access this datastructure:

1. Search through the array to find all instances of your widget
2. Inside each instance find the style settings you have recorded and output them using [`wp_add_inline_style`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_add_inline_style).