# How to link external JavaScript files?

Tags: customization, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I am working on a custom WordPress theme. I have everything working perfectly so far except for one thing: the external JavaScript files will not work.

I followed the exact advice from the links [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/441/how-to-link-external-jquery-javascript-files-with-wordpress) and [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/556/what-is-the-preferred-way-to-add-custom-javascript-files-to-the-site), but it still does not work.

I have searched the codex, checked source code, used firebug. I have no idea why this is not working. Unfortunately, due to an [NDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-disclosure_agreement), I am not allowed to give you any of the actual code from the site, or a link to it. So I will have to explain as best as I can.

I have used the `wp_enqueue_script()` to include the files in the `functions.php` file. The script tags in the head are as follows:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.xx.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.js?ver=1.4.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.xx.com/wp-content/themes/twentyten/scripts/custom.js?ver=3.1'></script>
```

So the files are loading, but they just are not working. I was wondering if the `?ver=3.1` at the end of my `custom.js` file might have anything to do with it?

The code from my `functions.php` file:

```
function twentyten_custom_scripts() {
if ( !is_admin() ) // instruction to only load if it is not the admin area
{ 
   // register your script location, dependencies and version
    wp_register_script('custom_script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/scripts/custom.js', array('jquery') );
   // enqueue the script
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
}
}
add_action('template_redirect', 'twentyten_custom_scripts');
```

I am really lost at this point. I even changed all my:

```
$('#elem').hide();
```

to

```
jQuery('#elem').hide();
```

In the `custom.js` file according to the codex `wp_enqueue_script()` no conflicts wrappers section [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script), still nothing.

Oh, and I am needing this file to load into all of my *Pages*, but not on my *Blog*, as I have multiple static pages set up for the main site. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Just to clarify: The js-files are accessable from your browser if you just paste the url in the address bar and hit enter?

Comment: @Roman yes, they are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my point of view, this should be working. Maybe you can post your **custom.js** file here. It could be possible that this file has a syntax error or something similar. You could also test if the built-in jquery is working out of the box by adding a simple jquery-command in your **header.php**.

#### Some hints:

1. The action-hook `template_redirect` is used to include the file only on the front-page (so i can remeber). If you want to load the script after the theme is loaded, you can use the `after_setup_theme` action-hook.
2. You don't have to enqueue your jquery file manually, if you set jquery as a dependancy of your **custom.js**, like you did. The file will automatically be loaded from WordPress before your **custom.js** is attached.
3. Do you have added the `jQuery.noConflict();` at the beginning of your **custom.js**?

Some working example:

**functions.php**

```
function twentyten_custom_scripts() {
    if ( !is_admin() ) // instruction to only load if it is not the admin area
    { 
        wp_register_script('custom_script', get_bloginfo('template_directory') . '/scripts/custom.js', array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_script('custom_script');
    }
}
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'twentyten_custom_scripts');
```

**custom.js**

```
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // do your stuff e.g.
    jQuery("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
```

Comment: Ok, i tired all your suggestions, so something in there did the trick. It seems to be working now. Thanks Roman.