# loading javascript after jquery is loaded

Tags: theme-development, jquery

I want to load some javascript for the front page of my theme after jquery and jquery ui is loaded. what would be the hook to use?

I am aware of the functions.php and I have used is_front_page(). 
By inserting wp_register_script in functions.php, I can queue the script after the libraries I want loaded but I also want to load it only on the frontpage. 
Using is_front_page() on header.php, the script gets loaded ahead of jquery.

How could I load my javascript after loading the jquery and only on the front page?

Comment: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/441/how-to-link-external-jquery-javascript-files-with-wordpress

Comment: I do use enqueue, but I don't want to load my script on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enqueue the script in your functions.php instead of the header, wrap it in the conditional tags ( in your case `is_front_page` ) and use the proper enqueue dependency, you can change the load order by altering the `add_action $priority` parameter or use `$in_footer`