# wp_enqueue_script outside functions.php file?

Tags: theme-development

I want to include an optional template part in the theme which requires some jQuery plugin. Is it ok to include the wp_enqueue_script in that specific file? Or it should always be included in the functions.php file?

Also, is it ok to write some javascript code in that specific file?
The script works, but my question is about WordPress coding standard.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to Link External jQuery/Javascript files with WordPress](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/441/how-to-link-external-jquery-javascript-files-with-wordpress)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to enqueue it to the `get_template_part_{$slug}` action to keep all the scripts in one place & more organized. But you can do it either way you like